# Who are “my servants” in Isaiah 65: 13-15?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 65:13-15

> “Therefore, thus says the Lord God, “Behold, My servants will eat, but you will be hungry. Behold, My servants will drink, but you will be thirsty. Behold, My servants will rejoice, but you will be put to shame. Behold, My servants will shout joyfully with a glad heart, But you will cry out with a heavy heart, And you will wail with a broken spirit. You will leave your name for a curse to My chosen ones, And the Lord God will slay you. But My servants will be called by another name.”
>   ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭65:13-15‬ ‭NASB‬‬

Who are “My Servants” referring to? And who is God speaking to? Israel as a whole, or unbelieving/disobedient Israelites?

Comment: related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/17154/does-the-past-tense-in-the-suffering-servant-song-isaiah-53-refer-to-jesus

Answer (score 1):

**Who are “my servants” in Isaiah 65: 13-15?**

God's judgment against idolaters (65:1-12)

From verses 1-12 by means of his prophet  Isaiah, God is reproving the nation of Israel (Vs 2) for spiritually abandoning him, being rebellious, offering sacrifices to idols, eating swine's flesh,(Unclean food Lev.11:7)  worshipping the god of good fortune (Vs 11)  and sitting in graves (unclean according to the Law Numb. 19:14-16)e.t.c.

Isaiah 65:1-5  (NASB)

A Rebellious people destined to the sword, God allows the Babylonians to destroy Jerusalem and the temple. (read Vs 11-12)

> 65 “I permitted Myself to be sought by those who did not ask for Me; I
>   permitted Myself to be found by those who did not seek Me. I said,
>   ‘Here am I, here am I,’ To a nation which did not call on My name. 2
>   “I have spread out My hands all day long to a rebellious people, Who
>   walk in the way which is not good, [a]following their own thoughts,  3
>   A people who continually provoke Me to My face, Offering sacrifices in
>   gardens and burning incense on bricks; 4 Who sit among graves and
>   spend the night in secret places; Who eat swine’s flesh, And the broth
>   of unclean meat is in their pots. 5 “Who say, ‘Keep to yourself, do
>   not come near me, For I am holier than you!’ These are smoke in My
>   [b]nostrils, A fire that burns all the day.

In contrast,  verse 13-25 the prophet speaks of the spiritual and material things that await those that sincerely worship God- called his servants. God will bless his servants and their hearts will be full of joy. Eating and drinking are terms that imply spiritual abundance that will satisfy his true worshippers in contrast to those that have abandoned him, "they will cry with a heavy heart, And you will wail with a broken spirit'" (Vs 14) Due to lack of spiritual food.

Isaiah 65:13-15  (NASB)

> 13 "Therefore, thus says the Lord [a]God, “Behold, My servants will
>   eat, but you will be hungry.  Behold, My servants will drink, but you
>   will be thirsty. Behold, My servants will rejoice, but you will be put
>   to shame. 14 “Behold, My servants will shout joyfully with a glad
>   heart, But you will cry out with a heavy heart, And you will wail with
>   a broken spirit. 15 “You will leave your name for a curse to My chosen
>   ones, And the Lord [c]God will slay you. But [d]My servants will be
>   called by another name."

Conclusion:

His Servants: Refers to the remnant of faithful Israelites whom God showed his mercy and restored them to Jerusalem from the Babylonian captivity. Verses 10,13-15 tell us of the blessings that await those faithful Israelites, under the governorship of Zerubbabel assisted by High Priest Joshua, helped re-establish true worship in Jerusalem. ( Ezra 5:1-2) The prophecy had its first fulfillment in the 6th B.C.E. and constituted the  "new heavens and a new earth." (Vs17)

The fact that Apostle Peter reiterated  Isaiah's prophesy shows that it also has a future fulfillment. The Apostle wrote:  " But according to His promise we are looking for new heavens and a new earth, in which righteousness dwells." (2 Peter 3:13 NASB)

Comment: Very like the Beatitudes. But the new heavens and the new earth that Peter was looking for arrived in the first century when  his servants obtained the new name: Christians: *[2Co 5:16-17 NKJV] (16) Therefore, from now on, we regard no one according to the flesh. Even though we have known Christ according to the flesh, yet now we know [Him thus] no longer. (17) Therefore, if anyone [is] in Christ, [he is] a new creation; old things have passed away; behold, all things have become new.* The new Jerusalem is the new covenant, which Jesus ratified in his blood.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Isaiah 65:13-15

> 13 Therefore this is what the Sovereign Lord says:
> “My servants will eat, but you will go hungry;
> my servants will drink, but you will go thirsty;
> my servants will rejoice, but you will be put to shame.
>
> 14 My servants will sing out of the joy of their hearts,
> but you will cry out from anguish of heart and wail in brokenness of spirit.
>
> 15 You will leave your name for **my chosen ones** to use in their curses;
> the Sovereign Lord will put you to death, **but to his servants he will give another name**.

These servants are the chosen ones and they will have a new name. They are those written in Isaiah 65:1;

> “I revealed myself to those who did not ask for me;
> I was found by those who did not seek me.
> To a nation that did not call on my name,
> I said, ‘Here am I, here am I.’ (NIV)

and those written in Isaiah 65:9

> I will bring forth descendants from Jacob,
> and from Judah those who will possess my mountains;
> my chosen people will inherit them, and there will my servants live. (NIV)

Obviously, these servants are no longer just descendants of Jacob, they are chosen from other nations too. Then what would be the new name? Would it be **"Christians"**?