How can the physical death of Jesus atone for both the death of the flesh and the condemnation of the soul?
Colossians 1:14 - In whom we have redemption through his blood, even the forgiveness of sins:
Romans 6:23 - For the wages of sin is death, but the gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord.
Do the wages of sin cause the death of the flesh and damnation of the soul (2nd death)?
If so then how does the bodily death of Jesus account/atone for both deaths?
Can this be reconciled by scripture?

This question seems to be based on "If sin causes spiritual death".  Is that a hypothetical question, or the doctrine of some specific denominations, or is there biblical text that states this?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'm inclined to say that this question is not clearly asked, as the key distinction of physical vs spiritual death is not mentioned in either of those verses. And personally, I'd say that sin causes holistic death, and Jesus brings holistic salvation and resurrection.

@Ray We know sin causes death. It is more to understand how exactly the death of 2 types is atoned for with a physical death using scripture. There is no hypothesis involved. As you can tell, not many have been able to provide an adequate answer to the question, which focuses a light on a real potential problem on understanding how the atonement applies

@Curious - Sin may infact cause holistic death to everyone, but what about the one who provided the atonement? Are you willing to say that sin caused holistic death in Christ? See the problem?

@Constantthin It's a valid question. Stop complaining about questions just because you don't understand it. Other have given descent answers, which means the question is not the problem.

Well, there is no scripture that says that Jesus's death atones for the spiritual death of the people. In fact there's no scripture in the NT that says Jesus's death atones for death. Actually I'm not aware of anything that says that Jesus's death atones. And no where does it say that it is death that is atoned for, but it is our sins that the atonement is for.
It is not the death of Jesus that atones or propitiates for our sins, but it is Jesus himself.

1 My little children, I am writing these things to you so that you may not sin. But if anyone does sin, we have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous. 2 He is the propitiation for our sins, and not for ours only but also for the sins of the whole world. 1 John 2:1-2


10 In this is love, not that we have loved God but that he loved us and sent his Son to be the propitiation for our sins. 1 John 4:10

And

23 for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, 24 and are justified by his grace as a gift, through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus, 25 whom God put forward as a propitiation by his blood, to be received by faith. This was to show God’s righteousness, because in his divine forbearance he had passed over former sins. Romans 3:23-25

In the last quotation, again Jesus himself is the propitiation for our sins, but it makes clear that the means by which he becomes this is through his blood - his life poured out through death. This is echoed in Hebrews which explains that it is through Jesus suffering that he became the eternal source of salvation for all who obey him.

8 Although he was a son, he learned obedience through what he suffered. 9 And being made perfect, he became the source of eternal salvation to all who obey him, 10 being designated by God a high priest after the order of Melchizedek. Hebrews 5:8-10

So, careful reading reveals that it is not the death of Jesus that atones, but Jesus himself who is the atonement, the eternal source of salvation for us which he himself became through the suffering of his death. The New Testament exclusively identifies Jesus himself as the propitiation or atonement for our sins. We will misconceive the atonement if we think it's the death of Jesus that atones and not Jesus himself who having died is the living atonement. The atonement isn't an event. It is a person, a priest and a king.

The LORD has sworn
and will not change his mind,
“You are a priest forever
after the order of Melchizedek.
-Psalms 110:4

If our sins our atoned for by the very person of our Lord Jesus Christ than for those who are in him there is no condemnation. No eternal damnation. No eternal death.

There is therefore now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus.
-Romans 8:1


I don't agree with your summation, though it is the closest by far. 'he became the source of eternal salvation'. How did he 'become', by obedience unto death, which made him sinless. His whole life was to prove out his sinlessness by doing God's will and not his own - as he stated several times. Heb 5:7 shows that he was 'saved from death all the days of his flesh' because he could have sinned in any one of them, rendering hisSELF useless. It is not Jesus who enables salvation but his perfect sinless blood as the unblemished Lamb.

@Steve "It is not Jesus who enables salvation but his perfect sinless blood as the unblemished Lamb." I dunno. We seem so close. It seems like you don't accept Hebrews 5:9 for what it literally says. He was made (by God) perfect and became the eternal source of salvation. Sure he had to prove out his sinlessness doing the will of God, but having done so he he himself becomes the propitiation, the eternal source of salvation, due to his proven righteous character as his proven character as a man thru death is part of his identity and is what God ultimately finds pleasing and appeasing in him.

I got the sense from your answer that Jesus was the source of salvation because of who he was by default not by how he accomplished it - which then made him able to be the Lamb. IOW, he wasn't the Lamb until he said 'it is finished' - thus remaining sinless until the very end. You missed the "being" made perfect (H 5:9), While he was always without sin, he had to remain without sin in order to be perfected.

Of course he was always the Lamb, but this had to be proved by his obedience. Heb starts out with, "Although he was a son..." this of itself was not enough! It was not enough just being Jesus, UNTIL he has proved himself obedient to death. Perhaps a fine point, but I think worth making to not overlook what and how he became the Lamb and what the blood of a sinless man tested in all things can accomplish. The 'Jesus is God' camp have no idea why being God makes it a complete sham -  He was always the Lamb no matter what! How untrue that theology is and how demeaning to his faithful obedience.

@Steve – You said: “It is not Jesus who enables salvation but his perfect sinless blood as the unblemished Lamb”. I think this is Scripturally untrue. Our justification/reconciliation is through the blood and death of Christ. But salvation is indeed through His Life and Resurrection. “Much more then, being justified now by His blood, we shall be saved from the wrath through Him. For if while being enemies we were reconciled to God through the death of His Son, much more, being reconciled, we shall be saved by His LIFE” (Rom 5:9-10).

He Himself declared: “I AM the Resurrection and the Life. The one believing into Me, though he die, he shall live” (John 11:25).

@Steve, I literally quoted Heb 5:9 and cited it to you specifically in the comments. I also said "the eternal source of salvation for us which he himself became through the suffering of his death." I think you should be supportive of my answer which is consistent with your comments. I never said he was the propitiation by default. But it is he, the person, who is the propitiation and not some specific event. Forgive me, but it seems like you're in such disagree mode that you don't see that we're 100% aligned. I just don't use the exact language & emphasis you prefer.

@Steve, I added a little additional language. Hopefully that helps.

Excellent answer. "He himself is the merciful provision and satisfaction concerning our sins; not concerning ours alone, but rather also concerning all the world." (1 John 2:2)


Physical death is the separation of the soul from the body, and spiritual death is the separation of the soul from God. - (GotQuestions)
Sin created a spiritual separation from God. Physical death and spiritual death was a consequence of sin. A consequence that required payment.
Leviticus 17:11

For the life of the flesh is in the blood, and I have given it for you
on the altar to make atonement for your souls, for it is the blood
that makes atonement by the life.

In the Old Testament blood was shed for the atonement of souls. "blood" means the there was a necessary physical sacrifice for atonement. This means that physical death, a physical act, has spiritual implications. We will see shortly how so.
Hebrews 9:22 says,

Indeed, under the law almost everything is purified with blood, and
without the shedding of blood there is no forgiveness of sins.

Consider also:
1 Peter 2:24

He himself bore our sins in his body on the tree, that we might die to
sin and live to righteousness. By his wounds you have been healed.

Isaiah 53:5

But he was pierced for our transgressions;
he was crushed for our iniquities; upon him was the chastisement that brought us peace,
and with his wounds we are healed.


How can the physical death of Jesus atone for the spiritual death of people?
The answer is because that's not all that happened. A normal animal sacrifice is sacrificed and stays dead.
1 Peter 3:18 says,

For Christ also suffered once for sins, the righteous for the
unrighteous, that he might bring us to God, being put to death in the
flesh but made alive in the spirit,

Jesus' physical death dealt with the consequence of sin, however His resurrection: being made alive in the spirit, addressed the totality of spiritual death.
Romans 4:25

He was delivered over to death for our sins and was raised to life for
our justification.

Death was for our sins. Him raising to life was for our justification.

Leviticus 17:11: Blood is required for atonement.
Hebrews 9:22: Shedding of blood is needed for forgiveness.
1 Peter 2:24: Jesus' wounds heal us; He bore our sins on the tree.
Isaiah 53:5: Jesus' suffering and wounds brought us peace and
healing.
1 Peter 3:18: Jesus died in the flesh and was made alive in the
spirit to bring us to God.
Romans 4:25: Jesus was delivered for our sins and raised for our
justification.

It's not just His death, but His wounds, suffering, and resurrection. The righteous for the unrighteous.
There was death in the flesh and being made alive in the spirit. It addresses both the physical separation (death) and the spiritual separation (sin). The resurrection demonstrates of His power over both.
Spiritual death is a state of separation from God. It's being cut off from the divine presence and life that only God offers. It's a severance from our created purpose. It's an existence devoid of the peace and joy that comes from a relationship with God.
So, His death addresses the penalty for our sin, and His resurrection ensures that we can have eternal life.

Thank you for your answer. He did die in the flesh and was raised in the spirit, but his flesh raised also to incorruption. What does spiritual death look like?

My response would be: Spiritual death is a state of separation from God. It's being cut off from the divine presence and life that only God offers. It's a severance from our created purpose. It's an existence devoid of the peace and joy that comes from a relationship with God.

Bingo. So do you remember anything like a separation happening?

Up-voted +1. But the expression His righteousness was exchanged for our unrighteousness. is not found in scripture. 'Righteousness of God' is stated ten times in the bible : 'righteousness of Christ (or Jesus)' is not. ('Jesus Christ righteous' is a title related to advocacy, not sacrifice and justification.) But a good answer. Appreciated.

On this theme I like also Romans ch6 vv3-5 (we are taken by Christ through the death-and-resurrection sequence).

It is quite interesting that you took the definition of 'physical death' from an outside source (GotQuestions) other than the Scripture!

@NigelJ I appreciate the comment. I have edited my answer to stay more scripturally accurate.

@Jason_ You are most welcome. And thank you.

@Biff. You ask, "What does spiritual death look like?" You might want to ask the rich man at Luke 16:19-31. The better question should be, "What does spiritual death feel like. Please read it!

@Mr Bond - I asked the question referring to Jesus' crucifixion.  I am not concerned with Sheol regarding this. I was asking if there was anything apparent on the cross that shows a separation.

@Biff. I was simply addressing your statement when you said, "What does spiritual death FEEL like. As to your question spiritual death refers to the separation from God caused by sin. All humans are sinners, period. Jesus was a perfect sacrifice to His Father paying the debt of humanity's sins through His blood since He was sinless and willingly gave His life. Hebrews 4:15 states that Jesus was without sin. Acts 20:28 states that God purchased the church with His own blood. Jesus had two natures, one human on His mothers side, and one of deity on His Fathers side. Btw, when were you in Vietnam

@Mr Bond - In Vn from 2010 - present. I looked at my comment again and I did not say feel, I did say look.  'What does spiritual death look like? – Biff Yesterday'

@Biff. Troi oi, your right I did use"feel" instead of "look." Keep studying your  Bible.

@ Mr Bond - Hãy nâng cao danh Chúa Giêsu trong mọi quốc gia. Được phước.

@Biff I see you believe in the Trinity, good! I arrived  in Vietnam in January 1968 and two weeks later was the Tet offensive. One of the most horrible times of the war. I'm so grateful that God saw fit to keep me alive and have Him use me. I've been a Christian 62 years now. Like I said to you, "Keep studying your Bible and "NEVER" give up. Blessings to you and yours.

The scriptures often seem to employ progressive revelation into a culture that’s vastly different than ours. So, let’s look backwards in history.
During the ministry of repentance and consecration by John the Immerser (from the Greek word, baptismós), he informed his listeners that a previously unremarkable person would emerge who has great authority and honor. And then we read

The next day he saw Jesus coming toward him, and said, “Behold, the
Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world . . .  And I have
seen and have borne witness that this is the Son of God.” – John 1:29,
34 (ESV throughout)

We should ask ourselves, what the term, “the lamb of God,” meant to first-century Galileans and Judeans, and from where that term originated.

Probably, the first thing that Judean or Galilean listeners would immediately have thought of was the role of a lamb as a peace offering or as an offering in substitutionary redemption and atonement for sin according to Torah.


For the life of the flesh is in the blood, and I have given it for you
on the altar to make atonement for your souls, for it is the blood
that makes atonement by the life. – Leviticus 17:11


Next, they would have remembered the commandment delivered by Moses as described in Exodus 12. This was a sacrifice of an unblemished, year-old male lamb, either a sheep or goat, for each household at the beginning of each year to escape the judgment of God against the tenth plague that would kill all the firstborn in Egypt, both humans and animals.


The Lord said to Moses and Aaron in the land of Egypt, “This month
shall be for you the beginning of months. It shall be the first month
of the year for you. Tell all the congregation of Israel that on the
tenth day of this month every man shall take a lamb according to their
fathers' houses, a lamb for a household. – Exodus 12:1-3
. . . and you shall keep it until the fourteenth day of this month,
when the whole assembly of the congregation of Israel shall kill their
lambs at twilight. Then they shall take some of the blood and put it
on the two doorposts and the lintel of the houses in which they eat
it.” – Exodus 12:7, 8

Some people have noticed the similarity to dabbing blood on a doorframe with the sign of the cross.

For I will pass through the land of Egypt that night, and I will
strike all the firstborn in the land of Egypt, both man and beast; and
on all the gods of Egypt I will execute judgments: I am the Lord.
The blood shall be a sign for you, on the houses where you are. And
when I see the blood, I will pass over you, and no plague will befall
you to destroy you, when I strike the land of Egypt. – Exodus 12:12,
13

The children of Israel would roast this lamb and eat it with unleavened bread and bitter herbs. This is the Passover that was also celebrated by Jesus and the disciples, now called “the last supper” and commemorated by Christians at communion.

And finally, the Galilean and Judean listeners would have remembered the first instance of substitutionary sacrifice. This is the conversation between Abraham, Isaac, and God, where God had initially commanded Abraham to kill his son, Isaac, as a human sacrifice.


And Isaac said to his father Abraham, “My father!” And he said, “Here
I am, my son.” He said, “Behold, the fire and the wood, but where is
the lamb for a burnt offering?” Abraham said, “God will provide for
himself the lamb for a burnt offering, my son.” – Genesis 22:7,8

In the event, God instead provided a ram caught in the bushes for Abraham to sacrifice in substitution for his son. Many people stumble over this horrifying scene. How could God ask for a human sacrifice from Abraham and why?
We cannot simply ignore the cultural context of that time! At that time and in many places since then all over the world, human sacrifice was not only acceptable, but it was commonly practiced. Here, God specifically rejects human sacrifice as a part of worship, and instead introduces the concept of substitutionary sacrifice, which later would become a significant aspect of ancient Judaism.
So, by introducing Jesus as “the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world,” John the Immerser informed his listeners that Jesus is the perfect, atoning lamb of God, which the Holy Spirit revealed to him as the Son of God. The people listening to John the Immerser would also recognize the allusion to Abraham and Isaac. God will provide for himself the perfect lamb for atonement for our sin for all time.
What John’s listeners most likely did not understand at that time was that God was going to sacrifice Himself in human form and in our place for the forgiveness of sin while still satisfying the need for justice. They didn’t realize that what happened with Abraham and Isaac was a foreshadowing of what would happen to Jesus.
There are many amazing parallels between Isaac and Jesus!

Do you get grossed out by the concept of sacrificing an animal to God? I know that I do. But it’s important to remember that in ancient times, the majority of people were rural. They typically bartered their livestock and produce rather than using money.
So, it would not be unreasonable to imagine that a modern equivalent of sacrificing a lamb to God would be to burn money instead.  So, let’s see, at the time of this writing, the price of an 80-pound live lamb is about $250.  Get the cash, an ashtray and a lighter. Then, get on your knees . . .

Re. that last para. Or how about doing what Jesus said to the rich young man as in this Q: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/what-is-the-significance-of-jesus-formula-of-sell-up-and-serve-in-matthew-19  And as regards OT sacrifices, how about answering this Q: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103527/what-evidence-was-there-in-old-testament-times-that-the-sacrifices-being-perfo

Anne, I'm not a member of the Christianity StackExchange. The difference between benevolent giving and sacrifice is interesting and significant. Then the sacrificial system required in Torah leaves no room for human creativity, only obedience. Consider God's response to the "strange fire" in Leviticus 10. Archeological testing of altar residue indicates that this might well have been cannabis.

Oh, does not being a member of the Stack Christianity site mean you cannot link on to those two Qs (or just that you cannot answer them?) Whatever, you would make an excellent contributor to the Christianity site! I appreciate your points in the comment above. Yes, the difference between benevolent giving and sacrifice is really significant.

Thanks, Anne. No, it's just that my time is limited and I've chosen not to participate there--at least at this time. Much of my time now is spent in research and writing with the intent of publishing a book that I'm titling, Decoding the Parables of Jesus. Yes, it would probably do better nowadays with a clickbait title such as Shocking Discoveries in the Parables of Jesus! or Jesus' Parables Finally Unmasked!.  ;-) But, feel free to use anything that I've written here if you think it would be helpful there.

An OP comment added, “If physical death = 1, and spiritual death = 2, then physical death minus spiritual death = minus 1. Math being used as an analogy.” Being a mathematical dunce, my analogy, which requires different categorisation, might have everyone muttering “What?” but here goes anyway. This different categorisation is based on Genesis showing that Adam and Eve first suffered spiritual death due to their sin, followed by physical death over 900 years later. So, my equation is:
Spiritual death = 1, Physical death = 2, Humans both spiritually and physically dead = 3.
Humans granted spiritual life are then minus 1, and when they die physically, they are then minus 2, which means that category 3 has ceased to apply / exist for them.
Before proceeding, it is necessary to show that, although the Bible does not speak of “spiritual death”, it certainly speaks of being dead to God, which is what the phrase in question means.

“Having the understanding darkened, being alienated from the life of
God through the ignorance that is in them, because of the blindness of
their heart” Ephesians 4:19
“And you, that were sometime alienated and enemies in your mind by
wicked works, yet now hath he reconciled in the body of his flesh
through death, to present you holy and unblameable and unreproveable
in his sight… Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was
against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way,
nailing it to the cross.” Colossians 1:21-22 & 2:14

All humans have to suffer physical death as “the wages of sin is death” (Rom. 6:23), so 1 cannot be avoided, even if spiritual death has been removed by God. They still have to die physically, receiving a physical wage for their physical sins. Yet when they die physically, that death is instantly and permanently removed: “It is appointed unto man to die once, and then the judgment” Heb. 9:27. Now, there is no more death for that person! They were transferred from death to life eternal because they became spiritually alive at the point of the ‘new birth’ (which is spiritual, not physical). They are how Adam and Eve were before they sinned – spiritually alive and with no danger of any kind of death as there was no sin.
As the question wants to know how Christ’s physical death deals with the problem of the spiritual death of sinners, the basic answer is that because the man, Jesus, died as a willing sacrifice without ever having sinned, he could bear – in his body, on the tree – the punishment for sin that God can never sweep under the carpet. As a substitute for the wrath of God on our sin, the punishment we deserve was borne by him. The Bible says he became sin for us (2 Cor. 5:21 us physical humans) so he had to die physically as proof that “the wages of sin is death”. Christ received the wage of physical death for our sins.  As he had never sinned personally, his death is clearly a substitutionary death, in our place. That is how Christ defeated death in its totality, taking away its sting, its victory. And because he was not “just” a physical human, but God incarnate, his death had the magnitude of efficacy needed to deal both with spiritual death AND physical death, for in God’s scheme of things, both go together.
Sin brings both spiritual death, and physical death for humans. The physical death of the man, Jesus, followed by his resurrection from the grave BY the Spirit, with a glorified body, proves that both spiritual, and physical death had been dealt with, once for all time.  His sacrifice had dealt the death-blow to sin and death. It had to be a physical death as “without the shedding of blood there is no forgiveness” Heb. 9:22, but it also had to be the death of God incarnate to include victory over spiritual death.

Thanks for your answer Anne. I have a couple things to say. The math was merely an analogy. If you were looking at it as a real math, then oops, that wasn't intended in the OP. #2 Things cannot go back to the way they were before they sinned. The tree of life was in the garden for a purpose, it kept Adam from dying as he consumed the fruit regularly. So death was outside the garden, which is why God had to seal off the garden. Genesis 1:31 -  Then God saw everything that He had made, and indeed it was very good. Notice the word 'perfect' is missing.

@Biff Noted your points. Just to say that the first [Adamic] humanity was necessary for the second [new] humanity in Christ to come out of the first, which failed. "There will be a new heavens and a new earth, in which righteousness shall dwell". Righteousness of God dwelt in Eden but was rejected in favour of a different way of obtaining life eternal, so death entered the garden. But in heavenly Jerusalem the Tree of Life appears again and will be partaken of by the renewed humanity; renewed through the last Adam.

I am adding the following to clarify what I wrote earlier, to give a better explanation
of how does the bodily death of Jesus accounts for "both deaths" which according to scripture is one death.
The body that God created in Genesis is called a living soul and named it Adam. That is what began to die after he ate from the tree of good and evil. Death was passed on to all men because Adam represented the first Adam, which was a living soul.

"Thus it is written also, the first man Adam “became a living soul;” the last Adam a vivifying Spirit.


"Adam was placed in the garden as a “living soul.” Then he became a dying soul outside the garden. And nine hundred thirty years after his creation, he ended up as a “dead soul”. From alive to dead. When we compare this with “the last Adam”, we see the exact opposite: from dead to incorruptible life! For on Calvary, Christ surrendered his soul to death to be roused and resurrected once for all three days later. As a firstfruits and as “last Adam” and thus also as a guarantee that all mankind will follow him in that way. “Each in his own class”.


There is indeed a connection between “soul” and “life”. But that connection is only temporary. Because she ends in death. Exactly the place where the “vivifying spirit” just begins. Where spirit and life definitively leave death behind! But it is not only LIFE (yes, with all capitals!) But also vivifying. For just as through Adam death passed on to all people, so through “the lastAdam” Life goes on to all people! "
Andrea Piet

Death is a return to dust as Genesis 3:19 says.

By the sweat of your face you shall eat bread, till you return to the ground, for out of it you were taken; for you are dust, and to dust you shall return."


It is sown a soulish body; it is roused a spiritual body. If there is a soulish body, there is a spiritual also.
Opposite to a “soulish body” that is sown (buried) is a “spiritual body” that is resurrected.

God had not completed the first Adam until Christ the second Adam had died and been resurrected into a perfected man.  Immortality is then given through Him.

First of all it is a death of not just a man for our sins, but a death of God who adopted nature of man, according to which nature He died. Thus, there is an infinite difference between God’s death for you and an ordinary man’s death for you.
However, even if an ordinary man dies for you, this act is not at all simply bodily, but spiritual also, and even, far more spiritual than bodily.
For instance, a Frenchman in time of French civil wars in 18th-19th centuries, came to a prison to give final farewell to his revolutionary son who was to be executed. The guards shouted the surnames of the inmates to take them to a carriage for execution and before the son shouted, the father anticipated him and was taken to the execution place by the deceived guards, while the son was mistakingly released. Was it a physical action on the part of the father? Absolutely not! It was a self-sacrifice caused by intense love, and nothing is more spiritual than such a love, nothing! That physicality is secondary, is clear from the fact that we even do not ask whether  the father was shot, or beheaded, or hanged, for that changes nothing!
Now, God’s love to humanity is infinitely greater than this father’s love to his son.

Great story. I like what you said in response to my question, "this act is not at all simply bodily, but spiritual also", which I think actually begins to touch the solution to the original question. It looks like there is more though in the acts of Jesus' atonement.

simple addition and subtraction...Gen 2:7 KJ "And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul." dust (flesh) + breath of life (spirit) =  Nephesh (soul) Romans 5: 8,9 ASV "But God commendeth his own love toward us, in that, while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us. Much more then, being now justified by his blood, shall we be saved from the wrath of God through him." 1 TIM 2; 5,6 KJ "For there is one God, and one mediator between God and men, the man Christ Jesus; Who gave himself a ransom for all, to be testified in due time." Soul for Soul,  Adam = soul sold us into sin Jesus = soul died for us as ransom to pay for our sins so we are not subject to death.  Eze 18:4 KJ "Behold, all souls are mine; as the soul of the father, so also the soul of the son is mine: the soul that sinneth, it shall die."  Adam + sin = inherited death to all, Sinful human + Blood of Christ (his death) = forgiveness and life

As to the person who down voted this,  obviously you simply are prejudice, otherwise you would give reasons for the down vote. So open discussion can ensue.

I am giving a highly unpopular understanding of the issue. But this is Scripturally reconciled.
Answer
The riddle can be solved when we understand who a man is as created by God.
Man is physical and the “soul” is physical to say the least.
Explanation
Scripture says:

“And Jehovah God formed the man out of dust from the ground, and blew
into his nostrils the breath of life; and man BECAME a living
soul” (Gen 2:7).

Man does not HAVE a soul; man IS a soul, according to God’s own Word.
So, man is physical; soul is physical.
So, when a man dies, the soul also dies.
Soul is Physical
Jesus Christ Himself says that the “soul” is physical:

“Because of this, I say to you, Do not be anxious for your SOUL,
what you eat and what you drink, nor for your body, what you
put on. Is not the soul more than the food and the body than the
clothing?” (Mat 6:25).

How clearly the Lord explains this!
Just as clothing is for body, food and drink are for soul!
So, both soul and body are physical.
This is what the Word of God says.
Note:-
Some versions translate soul as “life” which also is correct. For example, ESV has this translation:

“Therefore I tell you, do not be anxious about your life, what you
will eat or what you will drink, nor about your body, what you will
put on. Is not life more than food, and the body more than
clothing?” (Mat 6:25).

Soul Dies
The Scripture again affirms:

“The soul that sins, it shall die” (Ezek 18:4).


“The soul that sins, it shall die” (Ezek 18:20).

We have seen that man IS a living soul. So when God said to Adam,

“for you are dust, and to dust you shall return” (Gen 3:19),

It is clear that Adam, both soul and body, is dust and both soul and body shall become dust.
It is significant that God didn’t say that Adam’s body is taken from the dust and so it shall return to dust. No, God said to the living soul, that is Adam, that “YOU” shall return to dust.
Man Sinned
When Adam sinned, it was not Adam’s body alone that sinned. Adam (both soul and body) sinned.
This is why God said, “YOU, (that is, Adam fully, both soul and body) are dust, and to dust YOU shall return”.
God didn’t say, ‘Your body is dust and to dust your body shall return’!
So, there are no “bodily” sin and “soulish” sin.
Whether you sin with your body or mind or soul, it does not matter; it is YOU who sin.
Jesus is Full Human
When the Word of God incarnated as a human being, He was a full Man, both soul and body.
Jesus says about His soul:

“Then He said to them, My soul is deeply grieved, even unto death.
Stay here and watch with Me” (Mat 26:38).


“And My soul is troubled, and what may I say? Father, save Me out
of this hour? But because of this I came to this hour” (John 12:27).

So, when Jesus died on the cross, the whole Jesus, both His soul and body, died and was buried in a grave.
Hence, the Scripture prophetically says:

“foreseeing, he spoke about the resurrection of the Christ, "that
His soul was not left in Hades (grave), nor did His flesh see corruption" (Acts 2:31).

Problem Solved
So, the problem mentioned in the OP is solved: Jesus didn’t die physically only. He died fully, in soul and body.
So, His full death is the atonement for both the death of the flesh and the death (the ”condemnation” of the OP) of the soul.
Conclusion
Sin, whether done physically or mentally, is a spiritual issue just as physical littering of waste on a public road is a social issue.
So, Jesus Christ is sufficient for everything and His one death is more than enough for atonement of both deaths.

-1 due to non sequitur here: "Man does not HAVE a soul; man IS a soul, according to God’s own Word. So, man is physical; soul is physical. So, when a man dies, the soul also dies." No. According to Genesis 2:7, Adam's physical body PLUS the non-physical breath of life from YHWH (niš·maṯ) made Adam "a living being" (lə·ne·p̄eš ḥay·yāh). Judaism considers humans dualistic: body and soul (personality) as described here: https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/body-soul/ . Based on I Thess. 5:23, humans are a trinity: https://bible.org/seriespage/2-man-trinity-spirit-soul-body .

I feel, after our discussion on QM, you have suddenly turned hostile to me (from positive to negative polarity).

Judaism does not consider Jesus of Nazareth as the Christ/Messiah who is to come. So I don’t depend too much on them. The “breath of life” (nishmath khayim) is physical life. God Himself, before the Flood, says that He will “destroy all FLESH in which is the breath of life from under the heavens” (Gen 6:17). This “breath” makes the difference between a “living soul” (Gen 1:21) and a “dead soul” (Num 19:11, 13). This physical breath can cease: “and his illness was very severe until he had no breath left to him” (1 King 17:17).

But I do agree that man has in him a non-physical element: the human spirit. But since the OP didn’t mention it, I too didn’t. The question was about body and soul.

There were two deaths in the death of Jesus Christ!
Let's look at it.
Adam's sin was physical. It resulted in two kinds of deaths:

Physical death. They would not live forever on earth.
Spiritual death. They became separated from God; God's kind of life and His presence.


“But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.” (Gen 2:17, KJV)

In the Hebrew text, 'surely die' is written מוּת מוּת which means 'die die'. The word 'death' is repeated twice. This expression 'die die' does three things.

It emphasizes the certainty of death occurring.
It emphasises the nature of death as gruesome.
It emphasises there will be two deaths.


“And he made his grave with the wicked, and with the rich in his death; because he had done no violence, neither was any deceit in his mouth.” (Isa 53:9, KJV)

The Hebrew word translated as 'death' is מֹתָ֑יו. The word is plural. So, it should have read '...in his deaths...'
            Hebrew｜mōṯˈāʸw｜death

         Part-of-speech: noun Gender: 
         masculine Number: plural 
         Person: not applicable 
         State: absolute 
         Verbal tense: not applicable 
         Verbal stem: not applicable

The word deaths is used in Jer 16:4 and Ezek.28:8,10
If we take the plurality of the word 'death', it portends that Jesus died twice or that Jesus experienced two kinds of deaths on the cross.
How can I show that Jesus died twice?

“And about the ninth hour Jesus cried with a loud voice, saying, Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani? that is to say, My God, my God, why hast thou forsaken me?” (Mat 27:46, KJV)

This is a spiritual separation or the spiritual death between Jesus and the Father.

“Jesus, when he had cried again with a loud voice, yielded up the ghost.” (Mat 27:50, KJV)

This is the physical death.
One death cannot take place without the other on the cross. Though they are two kinds of deaths, they are one. Both deaths are interwoven, so Jesus's death on the cross has both physical and spiritual results.

“And being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became obedient unto death, even the death of the cross.” (Php 2:8, KJV)

"...the death of the cross..." is one death in two.
This is why the death on the cross has physical and spiritual effects.

“And, having made peace through the blood of his cross, by him to reconcile all things unto himself; by him, I say, whether they be things in earth, or things in heaven.” (Col 1:20, KJV)

The shedding of his blood on the cross (his sacrifice and death) is the atonement that made peace between God and everyone who believed.

“For the life of the flesh is in the blood: and I have given it to you upon the altar to make an atonement for your souls: for it is the blood that maketh an atonement for the soul.” (Lev 17:11, KJV)

The blood is not only physical, it is spiritual. It carries both physical and spiritual entities. This is why the death of Jesus on the cross is one in two deaths. The blood binds both deaths as one.
This blood is the propitiation, it does two things amongst many others:

It washes away our sins. Heb.9:22
It satisfies God's wrath. 1Jn.2:2; 1Jn 4:10

The shedding of blood brings physical and spiritual death due to its value and what it represents.
Whenever I read the word 'death' in connection to Christ in the New Testament, I see two deaths resulting from the shedding of his blood.
Whenever I read the word 'atonement' I see two deaths because the blood carries both physical and spiritual lives.
This is how the shedding of his blood that leads to the deaths of Jesus atone for our spiritual death.

That's the conclusion I came to also. However your die die explanation is a little weird to me. I have looked in both the MT and the Paleo Hebrew syntax and I see Mot מוֹת (death) and ta mut תָּמוּת  (mortality) emphasizing 'truly die'

@Biff thank you for that observation
But from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, you must not eat from it; for on the day you eat from it, to die you shall be dying. CLV
(ภากฏ nin
thmuth muth
you-shall-die to-die )
From Interlinear Scripture Analyzer. https://www.scripture4all.org/
If you check Strong's Interlinear numbering:
(...thou shalt surely die. H4191 H4191 )
The word numbering is the same. This tells me that the root word is the same. The difference is the usage of words in the sentence.

Yes, Strongs uses Masoretic Text though which is modern Hebrew, as opposed to Paleo Hebrew in which the text was written. But either way, small differences.

This is based on assumption. Jesus was not forsaken - it was the grandest moment in all of creation for God and His obedient sinless son! He was simply reminding the hearers of who he was as prophesied thru Ps 22 by reciting the first and last lines ~ 'it is finished'. Thus your theory fails. See comment to Austin's answer.

@Steve. Thank you for your comment. No one knows it all. The word of God is multifaceted. You have emphasised a facet but that is not all there is. We all see and understand in parts. We all are growing. In all let us keep learning with great humility.

This may sound spiritual but it is not. There is no such wording in the bible as is used here. There is spiritual truth in the sufferings of Christ and in the death of Christ and in the shedding of his blood. We must adhere to the wording of the apostles if we would correctly understand the concepts involved.

First, we are not physical bodies that have a soul. We are living souls that have a body.

And the Lord God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed
into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.
(Gen. 2:7)

We were formed from the dust, and it was always the destiny of the body to return to the dust from which it came.

In the sweat of thy face shalt thou eat bread, till thou return unto
the ground; for out of it wast thou taken: for dust thou art, and unto
dust shalt thou return. (Gen. 3:19)

Death is a spiritual thing, however we view it from our mortal and fleshly perspective.
The death of Jesus Christ and the shedding of his blood for redemption has its foundation in the marriage bond between us and God. It's honestly a complicated bit of theology. I wrote a book on the subject, which I can't reasonably reproduce here. But generally speaking, to understand how it works, you have to begin by opening your mind to a new way of thinking. Most of us are taught that Christ was a heavenly version of the Old Testament sin offering. He was a spotless lamb who came and died for our sins (Jn. 1:29). The far-reaching application and effect of his sacrifice versus that of animals was merely a byproduct of his status as the son of God. Heavenly things require better sacrifices, so his greater sacrifice had a greater result (Heb. 9:23).
However, while there is some truth to this line of reasoning, it assigns too much focus and priority on the parallels to legalistic rituals, and neglects the stated purpose of his death. Christ fulfilled any number of such parallels. He is the word made flesh, the very image of the heavenly patterns foreshadowed in the law (Jn. 1:1, 14; Heb. 10:1). As such, these parallels are to be expected.
We know, for example, that he was our Passover. The time of his death is consistent with the Passover (Matt. 26:17-21; Mk. 14:12-18; Lk. 22:7-15). He arrived in Jerusalem on lamb selection day (Jn. 12:1, 12; Jn. 19:32-36; Exod. 12:46; Num. 9:12; Ps. 34:20). When the soldiers came to break the bones of the crucified prisoners, he was already dead, so his bones were not broken, which follows the statutes of the Passover (Jn. 19:31-37; Num. 9:12; Ps. 34:20). Paul even says that “Christ our passover is sacrificed for us” (1 Cor. 5:7).
Christ likewise died as a worthy offering, sacrificing himself so he could enter the very presence of God, the heavenly holy of holies, and make atonement for the world as the high priest would do on the Day of Atonement (Lev. 16:2-6, 11, 15; Heb. 9:6-7, 11-12). He is our high priest, according to the order of Melchisedec, who was “without father, without mother, without descent, having neither beginning of days, nor end of life; but made like unto the Son of God” (Heb. 7:1-17). And in the interest of pointing out the futility of trying to impose parallelisms on the significance of Christ’s sacrifice, it is worth noting in this instance that the high priest first made a sacrifice for himself on the Day of Atonement. It purified him before entering into the presence of God, where he would then make intercession on behalf of the people (Lev. 16:2-6, 11, 15). Christ offered his own self as a perfect sacrifice to gain access to the throne of God (Heb. 9:6-7, 11-12). His intercession on our behalf, according to the Day of Atonement ritual, was a related, but separate act. In other words, his death in this specific parallel was not a sacrifice intended for us, but for himself.
Our atonement was fulfilled through yet another parallel. In addition to being the high priest, Christ was also the scapegoat associated with the Day of Atonement. The high priest would select two goats. Lots would be cast, and the scapegoat would have the sins of the people laid upon its head and be led out of town (Lev. 16:5, 7-10, 21-22). Christ, the son of God the Father, and Barabbas, “son of the father,” stood before the people, paralleling the two goats (Bar (βαρ) is a prefix meaning “son of.” For interpretive comparison, see Jn. 1:42, 21:15-17 with Matt. 16:17). Jesus, chosen to be the scapegoat, was led out of town with the sins of the people, wearing a crimson cord of blood around his head from the crown of thorns, in an extended fulfillment of the priestly laws and practices (bYoma 41b).
There are many parallels I could list, though others require more extensive discourse. Suffice it to say, Christ’s fulfillment of these things was inevitable. The sacrifices and rituals were designed according to the pattern of what was to come. Until Christ came and the heavenly application of the traditions was put into action, the mystery of their purpose remained veiled and hidden (Matt. 13:35; Rom. 16:25; Eph. 3:9; Col. 1:26; 1 Cor. 2:7-8).
Thus, the parallels have no real bearing on the purpose of his sacrifice. In fact, the opposite is closer to the truth. While the comparisons to the Old Covenant law may be valid in their own right, and while his sacrifice may have accomplished the intended legal purpose for each, none of these analogous parallels are the stated reason for his death, which is composed of two individual parts; viz. the legal reason for his death, and what resulted from his death.
Beginning first with the latter, Christ, by his own mouth, specified that his blood was shed to establish the New Covenant, which Hebrews readily confirms (Heb. 9:15-17). A testament — as in a “last will and testament” — is not in force until the death of the testator. So long as Christ lived, there could not be a New Testament. It would have remained unrealized.

And he took the cup, and gave thanks, and gave it to them, saying,
Drink ye all of it; For this is my blood of the new testament, which
is shed for many for the remission of sins (Matt. 26:27-28).


And he took the cup, and when he had given thanks, he gave it to them:
and they all drank of it. And he said unto them, This is my blood of
the new testament, which is shed for many (Mk. 14:23-24).


Likewise also the cup after supper, saying, This cup is the new
testament in my blood, which is shed for you (Lk. 22:20).


After the same manner also he took the cup, when he had supped,
saying, This cup is the new testament in my blood: this do ye, as oft
as ye drink it, in remembrance of me (1 Cor. 11:25).

The other half of his death is the yang to the yin. You can’t make a new covenant without first disposing of the old one. A “new” covenant, as Hebrews says, makes the first “old,” so that it is ready to vanish away (Heb. 10:9-10, 7:12). Like any other contract, there is a necessity to void the previous agreement. Thus, the scriptures tell us in plain language that, “He taketh away the first, that he may establish the second” (Heb. 8:13). In so doing, there was “a disannulling of the commandment going before for the weakness and unprofitableness thereof,” which he then replaced with something new, “built upon a better hope and upon better promises” (Heb. 7:18-19, 8:6). Christ voided the Old Covenant, replacing it with something new, so that our obligation is no longer to the former, but to the latter (Heb. 10:9-10; Col. 2:13-14; Eph. 2:14-16). Otherwise, there would be legal ambiguities, not unlike the ones we often encounter in our doctrines, due to the fact that people fail to recognize the transition.
This notable theme of the law’s dissolution throughout Paul’s letters, most especially in Romans and Galatians, is the foundation of one of the more heated debates in modern Christendom. Since we are no longer “under the law” but “under grace,” do we still need to keep the law of Moses? And the simplest answer is no, at least from the perspective that the law of Moses is no longer the active covenant (Acts 15:5-29). With the establishment of the New Covenant and the disannulling of the Old, the law has been superseded. It no longer exercises authority over us (Rom. 7:1-6). Christ mediated a New Covenant, and to reiterate, he “taketh away the first, that he may establish the second” (Heb. 9:15, 10:9-10).
The Old Covenant is gone for those in Christ.
And in taking away the Old to establish the New, he necessarily voided the oath that bound Israel to the Old (which includes all believers who are grafted into the good tree), which is the subtle and elusive key to the whole act of redemption. As it says in Hebrews, it was by means of his death, which was done for the redemption of the transgressions under the Old Testament, that we are now able to receive the promise of eternal inheritance offered by the New Testament, which couldn’t be in force while he lived (Heb. 9:15-17). Voiding our oath initiated the provisionary loophole in the law as it pertains to oaths. It obligated him by law to bear our sins as a consequence, which he couldn’t otherwise have done. This sort of surrogate responsibility is not possible within the basic purview of the law. As I previously said, you have to dismiss the parallels to animal sacrifices and such. No man can serve as a ransom for another.

None of them can by any means redeem his brother, nor give to God a
ransom for him:    (For the redemption of their soul is precious, and
it ceaseth for ever:) That he should still live for ever, and not see
corruption (Ps. 49:7-9).

However, a husband can serve as a ransom for his wife, specifically in the case of a vow or an oath. This is how and why our marriage relationship with God is important. The marriage bond is the only way to accomplish the redemption that Christ accomplished.

If a man vow a vow unto the LORD, or swear an oath to bind his soul
with a bond; he shall not break his word, he shall do according to all
that proceedeth out of his mouth. […] If a woman also vow a vow unto
the LORD, and bind herself by a bond […] And if she had at all an
husband, when she vowed, or uttered ought out of her lips, wherewith
she bound her soul; And her husband heard it, and held his peace at
her in the day that he heard it: then her vows shall stand, and her
bonds wherewith she bound her soul shall stand. But if her husband
disallowed her on the day that he heard it; then he shall make her vow
which she vowed, and that which she uttered with her lips, wherewith
she bound her soul, of none effect: and the LORD shall forgive her.
[…] Every vow, and every binding oath to afflict the soul, her husband
may establish it, or her husband may make it void. But if her husband
altogether hold his peace at her from day to day; then he establisheth
all her vows, or all her bonds, which are upon her: he confirmeth
them, because he held his peace at her in the day that he heard them.
But if he shall any ways make them void after that he hath heard them;
then he shall bear her iniquity (Num. 30:2-3, 6-8, 13-15).

As our husband, God had the authority to void our (Israel’s) oath when we first made it, rendering us guiltless. But rather than void it, he boldly confirmed and established our oath with an oath of his own, swearing to render judgement. In which case, relative to what Christ did, disannulling the Old Covenant and the associated oath, not only could Christ serve as a ransom, the law demanded it. Having held his peace, and then making the law and the oath void after the fact, he was required to bear our iniquity.
That is why Christ had to die. That is why he was made to bear our iniquity. We were dead in our sins as oath-breakers. We were transgressors under the covenant. With God sworn to judgement and unable to take his own name in vain, the only way to save us from that judgement was to void the covenant and oath that made us guilty as sinners and oath-breakers, and then bear the resulting burden of our iniquity himself. So Christ “[blotted] out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way….” (Col. 2:14). He abolished the law of commandments in his own flesh, nailing it to the cross, so that all those who believe would be reconciled to God (Eph. 2:15-16; Col. 2:14).
So understand that although many things were fulfilled in the process of establishing the New Covenant, the parallels to base sacrifices of atonement and forgiveness are incidental. He didn’t die because he was a Passover sacrifice. He didn’t die because he was a scapegoat. He didn’t die as some random sin offering. God, declaring the end from the beginning, gave us the ritual of the scapegoat to show how Christ would one day be displayed with a criminal and be led out of town with the sins of the people. God gave us the example of the Passover to show how death would one day pass over those who are covered with the blood of Christ. God required the high priest to make a sacrifice to enter the holy of holies to show how Christ would one day sacrifice himself for that same honor.
They are all examples of heavenly things, and not the very image of the things themselves (Heb. 8:5, 10:1). Christ is the heavenly thing, and the law is paralleling his accomplishments, not the other way around. What he would one day do, the law reflects. It is the pattern and process by which he would do it that the law seeks to mimic.
Once you understand this simple truth, that Christ didn’t die to fulfill specific rituals of the law, but to replace one covenant with another, you can begin to see the light at the end of the tunnel. The purpose of his death, and the shedding of his blood, was to bring about a covenantal shift (Heb. 9:15-23). This is the Holy Grail of understanding. That’s what made the sacrifice necessary. That’s what makes salvation work. It’s all about the shift. He died because he voided the Old Covenant, bearing our iniquity in the process. And once he was dead, his testament was empowered, establishing the New Covenant, so that all who believe could receive eternal life.
That is what he died to accomplish. And this reality is an important distinction. If he died to be our scapegoat, or some other sin offering, our sins would indeed have been forgiven, until we sinned again. But his sacrifice “put away sin” once and for all and condemned it — all sin, past, present, and future — because his death paid the price demanded by the law to disannul the covenant that defined our sins and condemned us (Heb. 9:26-28; Rom. 8:3).
So there was an actual necessity for God’s own death in accordance with the law, due to the sins that he had to bear. That’s why he came to us as Jesus Christ, the man. God can’t die, so the Word of God, his very utterance, took upon himself the form of a humble servant, making himself a little lower than the angels, and became a man, “for the suffering of death,” that, “he by the grace of God should taste death for every man” (Heb. 2:9, 16; Phil. 2:6-11; cf. Isa. 45:21-23).
The “Lamb of God,” or more simply, “God’s Lamb,” wasn’t a spiritual lamb sent by God for us. God sent the lamb for himself, presented as his own spotless sin offering. While God himself had no sin of his own, he still took upon himself the burden and responsibility of our iniquity all the same, which comes with the price of death and curses (Deut. 27:26, 30:19). So he sent his own “lamb” to die in his place, laying upon that lamb the iniquity of the world. The oath-breaker must die, so Christ died. And he died on the cross in particular, because the oath-breaker must be cursed, and it is written, “Cursed is every one that hangeth on a tree,” whereby he became a curse for us (Jn. 1:1, 14; Gal. 3:13; Deut. 21:22-23).
Thus, Jesus was, indeed, the Lamb of God, and he did, indeed, take away the sins of the world. But he didn’t do that by dying as a sin offering for us. He did it by dying as a sin offering for God, who bore the sins of the world.
The end result is that God declared, and his law demanded, that we must die for sin, and so we died, because we are one with Christ. His law demanded that we must be cursed, and so we were cursed, because we are one with Christ. His death was our death, and his curse was our curse, so that every jot and tittle has been fulfilled for everyone who believes. When Christ said that “Till heaven and earth pass, one jot or one tittle shall in no wise pass from the law, till all be fulfilled,” he did not mean that he, or anyone else, had to emulate every act and commandment of the law (Matt. 5:18). Rather, for every living soul, “fulfilling all” is about following the natural and legal course of the law to the bitter end. The law promises life or death, blessing or cursing (Deut. 30:19). Those under the law who are found to be transgressors are condemned, and the natural and legal end consequence for such under the law is death and curses. So we are buried with Christ in baptism, and made dead through him so that we might be resurrected in the newness of life (Rom. 6:4-7; Col. 2:12-13). The old man is crucified with Christ, and hanged on a tree, cursed by the law. We are then “born again” as new creations, born first in the flesh by our mother, and again in the spirit, being quickened together with Christ (Jn. 3:3-8; Eph. 2:5; Col. 2:13). So by Christ’s death and by Christ’s curse, both he and we have fulfilled the law according to its ultimate purpose, bringing it to its concluding finality by the crucifixion of Christ. Our sins have been paid for in full. The declaration in the garden, that we would surely die, has been satisfied.
In the eyes of the law, we are dead (Rom. 6:3-11, 7:4; Gal. 2:19-20).
And that’s really the genius of it all. Flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God (1 Cor. 15:50). Salvation is not about escaping death. It is about embracing it, so we can be reborn in the newness of life. We weren’t merely forgiven by the sacrifice of a spiritual lamb. Such a view is an oversimplification. We were altogether set free from the condemnation of the law via its completion and disannulment.
The process of salvation takes us from one creation to the next. There are two lives, natural and spiritual; two births, flesh and spirit; two creations, terrestrial and heavenly; and two Adams from which we descend (1 Cor. 15:44; Jn. 3:5-6; Rev. 21:1; 1 Cor. 15:45-47). In Christ, we are descended from the new Adam, free from the promise of death in the garden, to live in a spiritual world where the law has no dominion, and where God’s declaration has been satisfied.
This is the root of the law versus grace concept. By his declaration that we would surely die, God was obligated to deliver us to death. And by his law, he was obligated to render judgement. The old man of the flesh must die (Rom. 6:6; Col. 3:9). This is the law. It is the ministry of death and condemnation. There has to be an amends for our transgressions.
But having been slain through the propitiation of Christ’s own death, God’s word and law have been fulfilled. As new creations descended from a new Adam, living in a new spiritual world, God’s hand is no longer forced to judgement. God can now simply say, “I forgive you,” and let that be the end of it. This is the condition of being under grace. It is the undeserved, freely given mercy and favor of God in our lives, through good times and bad, through our successes and our failings, whereas being formerly bound by his own word and oath, such mercy was not previously possible under his declaration or under his law.
We had to die before we could live.
And so by faith we die, and by faith we live, though it is not we who live, but Christ who lives in us (Gal. 2:20). We have been born again as new creations, living under grace rather than law, where the price of our iniquity has already been borne and satisfied, and where God is no longer obligated, by declaration or law, to impute our transgressions to us (Rom. 4:3-8).

Surely he hath borne our griefs, and carried our sorrows: yet we did
esteem him stricken, smitten of God, and afflicted. But he was wounded
for our transgressions, he was bruised for our iniquities: the
chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his stripes we are
healed. All we like sheep have gone astray; we have turned every one
to his own way; and the LORD hath laid on him the iniquity of us all.
[…] By his knowledge shall my righteous servant justify many; for he
shall bear their iniquities (Isa. 53:4-12).


How do you read, not add to.........Adam "became" a living soul Gen 2:7 KJ "And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul."

Apologies. I'm not understanding your question. Can you clarify?

Whoever down voted this well documented answer, make yourself known and provide an argument with scripture.

@AFrazier - "First, we are not physical bodies that have a soul. We are living souls that have a body." The body was created for man, the spirit was breathed in, and together the body and spirit became a "soul", or "animated". How does a body and spirit "become" a soul if the soul was first? This completely contradicts the verse you gave.

@AFrazier - also, it would be good if the OP was directly addressed and directly answered, rather than posting an entire chapter of a book (meaning the length of the answer). Most of the info given in this answer has very little to do with answering the  OP. It feels more like a self-serving boast of intellectualism rather than an actual solution to a dilemma. It should be condensed to an actual answer to the OP

Do you have a conclusion?

@Biff, I appreciate your perspective that this is some self-serving diatribe. But I assure you it is not. The question asked is not a simple one to answer. I tried very hard to condense the information. If I did a one or two paragraph blurb or similar, too many who read it would not fully grasp the answer and would dismiss it out of hand since it's not typical, however correct.

"You can’t make a new covenant without first disposing of the old one." Gets my vote!

Disagreeing with some comments to you, I do see how this long answer totally addresses the Q. To deal with the Law, the Old Covenant and how Christ fulfilled it so as to blot out "the handwriting of ordinances that were against us, which was contrary to us" taken out of the way by nailing it to the cross, all your points need to be made. +1 You said elsewhere that Christ is not another 'being', (as in God's being), not a 'demi-god'. Could you let me know if you see Christ as the 2nd person of the Trinity? Thanks.

@Anne. Yes, I see Christ as the second person in the trinity. But the concept of the trinity is that they are three godheads in one person. Christ is one expression of the whole. He's separate, but he's not. But the trinity is another subject altogether and hardly able to be thoroughly discussed in these limited notes.

Thank you for responding. I don't want to start any discussion here, as Comments are not for that. And I don't do "Chat". I was just curious about that one point! A definition of the Trinity I use is that the three persons share divine nature. The Father and the Son share the one, divine nature, with absolute unity of the Spirit in that nature.

Sin led Adam to Death.
Jesus came to set you free from sin through his teachings.
When you accept Jesus and follow him you are born again, you become the new creation or a new person and then you set free from sin.
This new person is going to have eternal life.
The Meaning of Jesus death.
Jesus spent all his time and life teaching us teachings that bring us closer to God and endured insults from the Jewish leaders and even torture and killing in order to present to us the divine message that enlightens our minds and makes us closer to God. Also, because of his death, he became an intercessor for humanity. We must also understand that his death is a motive for us to be saved from sin and from judgment.
So Jesus death in an indirect way led us to be free from sin and to get the eternal life.

Here's the problem we're trying to understand. Jesus physical death makes sense that it atones for the physical body (resurrection of the flesh) but where is the atonement for the soul that made the decision to sin and that receives final judgement? It is the soul that perishes.

Let me put in this way, the atonment for the soul that made the decision to sin is something that soul itself will do which is to born again/be a new creation/fight sin/obey Jesus teachings. Jesus came to pave the way by his teachings for this soul to  change and get its atonment. Also the soul by believing and following Jesus set free from the Law's punishment as it is set free from the Law. It is now under Jesus' Law.

Jesus physical death makes sense that it atones for the physical body (resurrection of the flesh) - I do not agree with you - Jesus death was a direct consequence for his preaching the word of God (the light) to human mankind (the darkness). The resurrection will happen by God to judge the world. It was planned by God and has nothing to do with Jesus death.

that is referring to the 2nd resurrection, not the first. I never said anything about you having to agree with me. The OP was not a statement of fact, but a question to gather opinions. I did not say the the physical death of Jesus atones for the body, but merely it makes sense, since the body is resurrected. But resurrection is not the atonement, it's a result of belief. So then, we're back to the beginning. How does Jesus' physical death atone for our soul's choice to sin. Flesh for flesh, eye for eye, soul for soul

Jesus death does not atone for anything. The soul made sin has to change to a new one or a new creation (by following Jesus' teachings) and the body will perish because corruption does not inherit incorruption.

did you seriously just say that Jesus' death does not atone for anything? I would think again about that comment, delete it and recomment. I'll wait...

You can review Peter Abelard or Faustus Socinus views on atonment or the martyrdom theory of atonement.

@Biff   no need to add to or complicate.   We are souls, we do not have a soul. Adam "became" a soul      Jesus was a soul. his death equals the redemption price for Adams sinful soul.  Jesus died so we do not have to.   Gen 2:7 KJ "And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul."

@Gamel Thomas    Wow, so you beleive we have no hope, without blood there is no forgiveness.  Atone= to pay the price, Adams life sold to sin,  Jesus life pays the price=atone.  Heb 9:12 KJ " Neither by the blood of goats and calves, but by his own blood he entered in once into the holy place, having obtained eternal redemption for us."  Note Heb. 9: 13-28 to help you understand redemption.   Also note Col 1:20  ASV  "and through him to reconcile all things unto himself, having made peace through the blood......'"

@ACME - then what are you after the body returns to dust and the spirit returns to God? If the body was formed and the spirit was added causing animation to both, then what is animated when the flesh and spirit return to their rightful places? Don't complicate things meaning 'just agree with you'. Sorry, I'm not going to agree with a partial idea.

@ACME, I think Heb 9:12-23 is speaking about the things in the earth (sacrifices, priesthood, Moses Testament,etc) which all were a shadow that refered to the real things which would took place in heaven that is the work of Jesus as an our intercessor who appears now in the Heavenly Temple to ask God to forgive us our sins. I mean he did not die to appease a fury God or to pay God a price in a literal form.

@Biff  Dead, non existent awaiting resurection back to life   Eze 18:4 KJ "Behold, all souls are mine; as the soul of the father, so also the soul of the son is mine: the soul that sinneth, it shall die." Die, death, nonexistence  Oxford dict " Death: the action or fact of dying or being killed; the end of the life of a person or organism."

@ACME In the resurrection, you will need your body back. How about the spirit, since it returned to God, are we going to get that back and become a living soul again? I think this might be a problem with the term used by Jesus referring to someone as 'sleeping' instead of dead. I get that they are actually dead, but how would the soul live without a body and a spirit in Sheol?

@Biff  Ps 104: 29,30 KJ ".....thou takest away their breath, they die, and return to their dust. Thou sendest forth thy spirit, they are created:...."   Job 33: 4 KJ "The Spirit of God hath made me, and the breath of the Almighty hath given me life."

@Biff    Shoel is the grave, nothing "lives" in sheol except bugs.  as to resurrection note Jesus words  at Luke 20: 37,38 KJ  "Now that the dead are raised, even Moses shewed at the bush, when he calleth the Lord the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob.   For he is not a God of the dead, but of the living: for all live unto him."  so God retains perfect memory of each person and as his will directs, the spirit creates, or in this case regenerates.  Matt. 19: 28,29

Yeah but Lazarus spoke to Abraham in Sheol. Obviously he was still in a very uncomfortable existence. There was still a soul there somehow even without spirit and body. So then this soul thing doesn't add up. Maybe soul on the creation account is a bad choice of words.

[A disclaimer. I believe that the crucifixion of Christ can be compared to a Swiss Army knife, in that it can serve more than one purpose. Below is one of them.]

Christ didn't have any sin. But God made him [to symbolically] become sin for us”. (2 Cor 5:21)

According to Gal 3:13 it was on the cross that Jesus became symbolic sin for us. But we need to examine the entire Passion Week to discover the reason behind it. What stands out most is his command to his disciples to buy swords because the scripture must be fulfilled about him (symbolically) mixing with transgressors. (Luke 22:36,37).
What also stands out are his words: ”Take this cup of suffering away from me” (Luke 22:42) which besides a natural agony about the coming suffering also could serve as a symbolic proof of repentance from mess coming from mixing with reckless symbolic drunkards:

“and he begins beating the other servants, partying, and getting drunk.” (Mat 24:49; NLT)

The phrase ‘cup of suffering’ originates from Bible verses such as Jer 25:15,16 and Eze 23:33. These verses are about the consumption of strong toxic beverages, suggesting that the Passion Week may be God’s clever way of warning us about drugs potentially deadly impact on soul and body:

Do not get drunk on wine, which leads to debauchery. (Eph 5:18).

Thus, through the passion week God is stereotyping carnality as revelling bar brawling (Mat 24:49), above the other possibilities of carnality found in Galatians 5:19-21. In contrast, in Gal 5:22,23 we find a list of the saving workings of walking in the spirit, crucifying the flesh:

“Those who belong to Christ Jesus have crucified the flesh with its passions and desires. (Gal 2:24).

Consequently, we can learn from the Passion Week, and the crucifixion and death of Christ, that we should crucify our flesh, before it crucifies us and puts the eternal fate of our entire constitution in jeopardy.

What? You realize Jesus was living the Nazarite vow? He didn't drink alcohol even though his disciples did. Why do you think he spit out the vinegar and wine / gall? The cup symbolically is a cup that fills with sins. In the garden, the cup is overflowing, meaning he is feeling the weight of the sin of the world upon Him. In contrast the woman in Rev17 that rode a beast held a golden cup filled with abominations in her hand, and she was drunk. So what is he really asking when he asks for this cup to be removed from Him?

@Biff, wrote: "You realize Jesus was living the Nazarite vow?" Is that your opinion or do you have biblical evidence to support this assertion?

@Constantthin Then why the mention of alcohol? What would the symbolism of alcohol be?

This does not answer the question. It goes into a cul-de-sac, as far as the question is concerned, deviating into the matter of alcohol. Jesus was known as "the Nazarene" - from the town of Nazareth. Nowhere does the Bible say he would never drink, or even taste a drop of alcohol, as for those with the vow of the Nazirite. That WAS the case for John the Baptist, but not Jesus. Unless this answer actually answers the question, it is in danger of being closed by the Moderators as being off-topic. Please modify your answer.

Moving the last sentence from higher up to the end changes nothing. The crucial point is that sin in our flesh already shows what our eternal fate will be; only Christ's crucifixion can deliver anyone from that. Once they have saving faith in the finished work of Christ, then they have crucified the flesh in the sense Paul meant. The sinless one voluntarily "became sin for us" so that the eternal fate we deserve be removed by him bearing God's righteous wrath for sin. That answers the Q. The Q is not about what we are supposed to do about it, such as avoiding alcohol!

And anybody that does not teach that the crucified Christ must come in our flesh is of, if not is, the Anti-Christ.

“Examine yourselves as to whether you are in the faith. Test yourselves. Do you not know yourselves, that Jesus Christ is in you?—unless indeed you are disqualified.” (2 Cor 13:5)

The idea that Jesus' death atoned for the sins of the people was formed only in the New Testament. I could not find a verse in the Old Testament where God required a human sacrifice for the sins of the people.
Some use the account where Isaac was about to be sacrificed by his father Abraham. Examining this we find that Isaac was not asked to be sacrificed to atone for the sins of the people. Isaac was about to be sacrificed on an altar. Jesus was not sacrificed on an altar, he was crucified on a stake.
The repentant Ninevites, Jonah 3:10 and David's confession to Nathan show that God forgives without a sacrifice.
Jonah 3:10 ASV
And God saw their works, that they turned from their evil way; and God repented of the evil which he said he would do unto them; and he did it not.
2 Samuel 12:13 ASV
And David said unto Nathan, I have sinned against Jehovah. And Nathan said unto David, Jehovah also hath put away thy sin; thou shalt not die.
The truly penitent are assured that God will forgive their sins. Psalm 40:6; 51:16-19; Jeremiah 7:21-23; Hosea 6:6; 14:2-3; Isaiah 56:7-8 and Micah 6:6-8.
Psalm 40:6; 51:16-19;
Sacrifice and offering thou hast no delight in; Mine ears hast thou opened: Burnt-offering and sin-offering hast thou not required.
For thou delightest not in sacrifice; else would I give it: Thou hast no pleasure in burnt-offering. The sacrifices of God are a broken spirit: A broken and a contrite heart, O God, thou wilt not despise. Do good in thy good pleasure unto Zion: Build thou the walls of Jerusalem. Then wilt thou delight in the sacrifices of righteousness, In burnt-offering and whole burnt-offering: Then will they offer bullocks upon thine altar.
Psalm 7:21-23 ASV
Thus saith Jehovah of hosts, the God of Israel: Add your burnt-offerings unto your sacrifices, and eat ye flesh. 22 For I spake not unto your fathers, nor commanded them in the day that I brought them out of the land of Egypt, concerning burnt-offerings or sacrifices: 23 but this thing I commanded them, saying, Hearken unto my voice, and I will be your God, and ye shall be my people; and walk ye in all the way that I command you, that it may be well with you.
Hosea 6:6 ASV
For I desire goodness, and not sacrifice; and the knowledge of God more than burnt-offerings.
Hosea 14:2-3 ASV
Take with you words, and return unto Jehovah: say unto him, Take away all iniquity, and [a]accept that which is good: so will we render as bullocks the offering of our lips. 3 Assyria shall not save us; we will not ride upon horses; neither will we say any more to the work of our hands, Ye are our gods; for in thee the fatherless findeth mercy.
Isaiah 56:7-8 ASV
7even them will I bring to my holy mountain, and make them joyful in my house of prayer: their burnt-offerings and their sacrifices shall be accepted upon mine altar; for my house shall be called a house of prayer for all peoples.
8The Lord Jehovah, who gathereth the outcasts of Israel, saith, Yet will I gather others to him, besides his own that are gathered.
Micah 6:6-8 ASV
6With what shall I come to the LORD And bow myself before the God on high? Shall I come to Him with burnt offerings, With yearling calves? 7Does the LORD take pleasure in thousands of rams, In ten thousand rivers of [c]oil? Shall I give Him my firstborn for my wrongdoings, The fruit of my body for the sin of my soul? 8He has told you, mortal one, what is good; And what does the LORD require of you But to do justice, to love [d]kindness, And to walk [e]humbly with your God?
Examining this idea, there are verses in the Old Testament that show that sins can be forgiven by repenting and praying, no human sacrifice was required. I could not find a verse where God required the sacrifice of a righteous man for the sins of the people.
Ezekiel 18:1-4, 19-23 shows that the righteous man cannot die for the sins of the wicked. The God of Bible does not punish the righteous for the sinfulness of another.

Isaiah 52:13 & 53

Jesus sacrifice was prophesied in OT, but they had animal sacrifices for forgiveness as a type of Jesus who would come and die for all men. "their burnt-offerings and their sacrifices shall be accepted upon mine altar" The latter OT books started to emphasize the futility of an animal dying for sins - they never did, but were an example only - as a shadow of who would come. The 'unblemished lamb' would be superseded by the unblemished LAMB who would prove his worth by obedience thru suffering and temptation - thus being made perfect he became the source of salvation for all.

@Steve. I would appreciate it if you can ask a question regarding a type of Jesus who come and die for all men. Then I could answer and address your comment better. The same with those that disagree with my answer. This idea of Jesus dying to atone for sins of the people was formed only in the New Testament. I could not find a verse in the Old Testament where God required a human sacrifice for the sins of the people..

Can you find passages which state blood is required?

@RevelationLad. Do you mean blood of a human being?

@AlexBalilo, would be interested if you responded to Biff's brilliant but perhaps cryptic comment regarding Is 52:13-53:12 as being a challenge to your claim that God would not require the sacrifice of a righteous man for the sins of the people.

@Austin.The comment section would not be  enough to address that. I would appreciate it if you turn what you call "Biff's brilliant but perhaps cryptic comment regarding Is 52:13-53:12 as being a challenge. You may find some answers to your comment here.  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/17154/does-the-past-tense-in-the-suffering-servant-song-isaiah-53-refer-to-jesu

Did blood of animals work? So if God requires blood and the blood of animals doesn't work what type of blood is required?

@RevelationLad. I will respond to your comment when you post them in a question. I can't find a verse in the Old Testament where God required a human sacrifice(blood of a human being) for the sins of the people.

There are a lot of things which are not explicit in the OT but are implied. You do not find a unique Son of God, but you believe Jesus is the Son of God. If blood is required and the blood of animals does not suffice, what does that imply?

@AlexBalilo "I can't find a verse in the Old Testament where God required a human sacrifice..." You're right, God does not want sacrifice but love and mercy (cf. Hos 6:6, Mica 6:8). Jesus' death is not human sacrifice but self-sacrifice, which is the greatest expression of love (Jn 15:13, 1 Jn 3:16). "But God shows his love for us in that while we were still sinners, Christ died for us" (Rom 5:8).

@Alex Balilo   Jesus and the Holy Spirit taught followers further revalation. We are not required only to accept "old testament" as complete truth.
