Is Isaiah's suffering servant the prophet Jeremiah?
Read what Jeremiah says about himself and compare his statement to Isaiah. "But I was like a gentle lamb led to the slaughter. I did not know it was against me they devised schemes, saying, . . .'Let us cut him off from the land of the living'" (Jer. 11:19) Then in Isaiah we read, "He was oppressed and afflicted, yet He did not open His mouth. Like a lamb led to the slaughter and like a sheep silent before her shearers, He did not open His mouth. He was taken away because of oppression and judgment; and who considered His fate? For He was cut off from the land of the living." (Isa. 53:7-8)

Seven times, the New Testament scriptures quote Isaiah 53 in relation to Jesus Christ - Matthew 8:14-17; John 12:37-41; Luke 22:35-38; 1 Peter 2:19-25; Acts 8:26-35; Romans 10:11-21. So, the answer is . . . . .  No. See further reading - Bible.org.

Nigel J- You have shared one scripture reference that quotes Isaiah 53:7-8. While there is scholarly debate, many biblical scholars believe that Acts 8:31-33 was likely added later to the text, as some early manuscripts do not contain these verses, suggesting they might have been a later interpolation or gloss added to the original text. Some of the oldest Greek manuscripts, like the Codex Sinaiticus and Codex Vaticanus, do not include verses 8:31-33, which strengthens the argument for later addition. It is okay to be wrong in this lifetime but in the end we shall know.

@NigelJ the NT being or not being an authority for what Isaiah 53 is about is entirely opinion based

Your assertions about V31-33 missing in Sinaiticus and Vaticanus are factually incorrect - I have copies of both and I have just checked them and these verses are found in both.  Now, V37 is missing from virtually all Greek MSS of Acts and appears to have been added by the Latin MSS about 1000 AD and later.

Why has this question accumulated 4 downvotes?

To truly determine who Isaiah 53 points to, we must consider the entirety of the prophecy. This answer may be lengthy, but I believe it is important for a thorough examination of the text. Does Isaiah 53 point to Jesus? Allow me to take a close exegesis of the scriptures and I will let you decide if it points to Jesus or not as it is typically considered.

Isaiah 53

Who has believed what he has heard from us?
And to whom has the arm of the Lord been revealed?

Many did not accept Jesus as the Messiah. This fulfillment of prophecy alone points to Jesus being the suffering servant:
John 12:36-38 -
While you have the light, believe in the light, that you may become sons of light.”
When Jesus had said these things, he departed and hid himself from them. Though he had done so many signs before them, they still did not believe in him, so that the word spoken by the prophet Isaiah might be fulfilled:
“Lord, who has believed what he heard from us,
and to whom has the arm of the Lord been revealed?”

The gospel writers and other New Testament authors quoted from this
passage several times, explaining that Jesus fulfilled the various
prophecies contained within it. [1]


2 For he grew up before him like a young plant,
and like a root out of dry ground; he had no form or majesty that we should look at him,
and no beauty that we should desire him.

Jesus was human and grew up in Nazareth.
Matthew 13:55 -
Is not this the carpenter's son? Is not his mother called Mary? And are not his brothers James and Joseph and Simon and Judas?
Philippians 2:7 -
but emptied himself, by taking the form of a servant, being born in the likeness of men.

3 He was despised and rejected by men,
a man of sorrows and acquainted with grief; and as one from whom men hide their faces
he was despised, and we esteemed him not.

Jesus was rejected by his own people.
John 1:11 -
He came to his own, and his own people did not receive him.
Luke 23:18 -
But they all cried out together, “Away with this man, and release to us Barabbas”—

4 Surely he has borne our griefs
and carried our sorrows; yet we esteemed him stricken,
smitten by God, and afflicted.

Again, Isaiah is quoted about Jesus:
Matthew 8:14-17 - And when Jesus entered Peter's house, he saw his mother-in-law lying sick with a fever. He touched her hand, and the fever left her, and she rose and began to serve him. That evening they brought to him many who were oppressed by demons, and he cast out the spirits with a word and healed all who were sick. This was to fulfill what was spoken by the prophet Isaiah: “He took our illnesses and bore our diseases.”

5 But he was pierced for our transgressions;
he was crushed for our iniquities; upon him was the chastisement that brought us peace,
and with his wounds we are healed.

Jesus was physically pierced during the crucifixion.
John 19:34 - But one of the soldiers pierced his side with a spear, and at once there came out blood and water.
1 Peter 2:24 - He himself bore our sins in his body on the tree, that we might die to sin and live to righteousness. By his wounds you have been healed.

6 All we like sheep have gone astray;
we have turned—every one—to his own way; and the Lord has laid on him
the iniquity of us all.

Jesus the Good Shepherd
1 Peter 2:25 - For you were straying like sheep, but have now returned to the Shepherd and Overseer of your souls.

7 He was oppressed, and he was afflicted,
yet he opened not his mouth; like a lamb that is led to the slaughter,
and like a sheep that before its shearers is silent,
so he opened not his mouth.

Jesus remained silent.
Matthew 26:63 - But Jesus remained silent. And the high priest said to him, “I adjure you by the living God, tell us if you are the Christ, the Son of God.”
1 Peter 2:23 - When he was reviled, he did not revile in return; when he suffered, he did not threaten, but continued entrusting himself to him who judges justly.

8 By oppression and judgment he was taken away;
and as for his generation, who considered that he was cut off out of the land of the living,
stricken for the transgression of my people?

Acts 8:32-35 -
Now the passage of the Scripture that he was reading was this:
“Like a sheep he was led to the slaughter
and like a lamb before its shearer is silent,
so he opens not his mouth.
In his humiliation justice was denied him.
Who can describe his generation?
For his life is taken away from the earth.”
And the eunuch said to Philip, “About whom, I ask you, does the prophet say this, about himself or about someone else?” Then Philip opened his mouth, and beginning with this Scripture he told him the good news about Jesus.

9 And they made his grave with the wicked
and with a rich man in his death, although he had done no violence,
and there was no deceit in his mouth.

Jesus’ body was placed in a rich man’s tomb.
Matthew 27:57-60 -
When it was evening, there came a rich man from Arimathea, named Joseph, who also was a disciple of Jesus. He went to Pilate and asked for the body of Jesus. Then Pilate ordered it to be given to him. And Joseph took the body and wrapped it in a clean linen shroud and laid it in his own new tomb, which he had cut in the rock. And he rolled a great stone to the entrance of the tomb and went away.

10 Yet it was the will of the Lord to crush him;
he has put him to grief; when his soul makes an offering for guilt,
he shall see his offspring; he shall prolong his days; the will of the Lord shall prosper in his hand.

Jesus’ sacrificial death gave us the promise of eternal life. (John 3:16)
Hebrews 9:28 - so Christ, having been offered once to bear the sins of many, will appear a second time, not to deal with sin but to save those who are eagerly waiting for him.

11 Out of the anguish of his soul he shall see and be satisfied; by
his knowledge shall the righteous one, my servant,
make many to be accounted righteous,
and he shall bear their iniquities.

One man's obedience the many will be made righteous.
Romans 5:18-19 -
Therefore, as one trespass led to condemnation for all men, so one act of righteousness leads to justification and life for all men. For as by the one man's disobedience the many were made sinners, so by the one man's obedience the many will be made righteous.

12 Therefore I will divide him a portion with the many,
and he shall divide the spoil with the strong, because he poured out his soul to death
and was numbered with the transgressors; yet he bore the sin of many,
and makes intercession for the transgressors.

Jesus was counted among criminals.
Luke 22:37 - For I tell you that this Scripture must be fulfilled in me: ‘And he was numbered with the transgressors.’ For what is written about me has its fulfillment.”
Hebrews 7:25 - Consequently, he is able to save to the uttermost those who draw near to God through him, since he always lives to make intercession for them.

+1. Excellent answer.

Thorough exegesis. Up-voted +1.

A biblically sound response deserving +1.

Well-presented answer but your interpretation of 53 is IMO incorrect see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/77814/33268 - as to sacrifice again see  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/75324/33268

Great answer. Well done, I think.

You need to provide a lot stronger evidence that 53 is a prophecy at all, when it is clearly simply the wailings of a 6 century BC jew over yet another subjection of Israel to a foreign power. https://ehrmanblog.org/does-isaiah-53-predict-jesus-suffering-and-death/

With apologiese the correct link regarding Isaiah 53 https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/82915/33268

Not once in the NT does any NT writer attribute the prophecies of Isa 53 to anyone except Jesus.  Indeed, the NT writers repeatedly say that the prophecies of Isa 53 were fulfilled by Jesus alone.  See especially Acts 8:32-35.  For more detail about the Isa 53 prophecies of Jesus, see the table below.
Now, let us be clear, the fact that someone appears to be a suffering servant such as Jeremiah, does not make that person the fulfillment of the prophecy - indeed, most prophets could be described as a suffering servant and were persecuted.  However, and this is the crux of the matter, when looking for the fulfilment of a prophecy, we CANNOT simply choose some elements that fit and ignore the rest - we must use ALL - each and every aspect specified to find the fulfillment.
Only Jesus Christ, the eternal Messiah, Israel's (both spiritual and literal) King and Redeemer, fulfills all the Isa 53's prophecies.



Isaiah 53 Prophecy
NT fulfilment




Isa 52:14 - Just as many were appalled at Him— His appearance was disfigured beyond that of any man, and His form was marred beyond human likeness
See Matt 20:19, Mark 10:34, Luke 18:33. John 19:1 - Then Pilate took Jesus and had Him flogged. Matt 27:29 - And they twisted together a crown of thorns and set it on His head. They put a staff in His right hand and knelt down before Him to mock Him, saying, “Hail, King of the Jews!”


Isa 53:1 - Who has believed our message? And to whom has the arm of the LORD been revealed?
John 12:37, 38 - Although Jesus had performed so many signs in their presence, they still did not believe in Him.  This was to fulfill the word of Isaiah the prophet: “Lord, who has believed our message? And to whom has the arm of the Lord been revealed? See also Rom 10:16, 17.


Isa 53:2 - For he grew up before him like a young plant, and like a root out of dry ground; he had no form or majesty that we should look at him, and no beauty that we should desire him.
John 1:14 – The Word became flesh and made His dwelling among us … . Phil 2:7 - but emptied himself, by taking the form of a servant, being born in the likeness of men.


Isa 53:3 - He was despised and rejected by men, a man of sorrows, acquainted with grief. Like one from whom men hide their faces, He was despised, and we esteemed Him not. (See also Ps 69:8 - I have become a stranger to my brothers and a foreigner to my mother’s sons)
John 1:11 - He came to His own, and His own did not receive Him. John 7:5 - For even His own brothers did not believe in Him.


Isa 53:4 - Surely He took on our infirmities and carried our sorrows; yet we considered Him stricken by God, struck down and afflicted.
Matt 8:16, 17 - When evening came, many who were demon-possessed were brought to Jesus, and He drove out the spirits with a word and healed all the sick.  This was to fulfill what was spoken through the prophet Isaiah: “He took on our infirmities and carried our diseases.” See also 1 Peter 2:24.


Isa 53:4 - Surely He took on our infirmities and carried our sorrows; yet we considered Him stricken by God, struck down and afflicted.
Matt 26:67, 68 - Then they spit in His face and struck Him. Others slapped Him and said, “Prophesy to us, Christ! Who hit You?” Matt 8:16, 17 - When evening came, many who were demon-possessed were brought to Jesus, and He drove out the spirits with a word and healed all the sick. This was to fulfill what was spoken through the prophet Isaiah: “He took on our infirmities and carried our diseases.”


Isa 53:5, 6 - But He was pierced for our transgressions, He was crushed for our iniquities; the punishment that brought us peace was upon Him, and by His stripes we are healed. We all like sheep have gone astray, each one has turned to his own way; and the LORD has laid upon Him the iniquity of us all.
Rom 5:6-8 - For at just the right time, while we were still powerless, Christ died for the ungodly.  Very rarely will anyone die for a righteous man, though for a good man someone might possibly dare to die.  But God proves His love for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died for us.


Isa 53:7, 8 - He was oppressed and afflicted, yet He did not open His mouth. He was led like a lamb to the slaughter, and as a sheep before her shearers is silent, so He did not open His mouth. By oppression and judgment He was taken away, and who can recount His descendants? For He was cut off from the land of the living; He was stricken for the transgression of My people.
Mark 15:4, 5 - Then Pilate questioned Him again, “Have You no answer? Look how many charges they are bringing against You!” But to Pilate’s amazement, Jesus made no further reply. Acts 8:32-35 - The eunuch was reading this passage of Scripture: “He was led like a sheep to the slaughter, and as a lamb before the shearer is silent, so He did not open His mouth. In His humiliation He was deprived of justice. Who can recount His descendants? For His life was removed from the earth.” … Then Philip began with this very Scripture and told him the good news about Jesus.


Isa 53:9 - He was assigned a grave with the wicked, and with a rich man in His death, although He had done no violence, nor was any deceit in His mouth.
Matt 27:57-60 - When it was evening, there came a rich man from Arimathea named Joseph, who himself was a disciple of Jesus.  He went to Pilate to ask for the body of Jesus, and Pilate ordered that it be given to him.  So Joseph took the body, wrapped it in a clean linen cloth, and placed it in his own new tomb that he had cut into the rock. Then he rolled a great stone across the entrance to the tomb and went away. See also 1 Peter 2:21.


Isa 53:12a - Therefore I will allot Him a portion with the great, and He will divide the spoils with the strong, because He has poured out His life unto death, and He was numbered with the transgressors.
Matt 27:38 - Two robbers were crucified with Him, one on His right hand and the other on His left. Luke 22:37 - For I tell you that this Scripture must be fulfilled in me: ‘And he was numbered with the transgressors.’ For what is written about me has its fulfillment.” See also Mark 15:27, 28


Isa 53:12b - Yet He bore the sin of many and made intercession for the transgressors
Hebrews 7:25 - Consequently, he is able to save to the uttermost those who draw near to God through him, since he always lives to make intercession for them. Rom 8:34 - Who is there to condemn us? For Christ Jesus, who died, and more than that was raised to life, is at the right hand of God—and He is interceding for us.




+1 "the fact that someone appears to be a suffering servant such as Jeremiah, does not make that person the fulfillment of the prophecy."

Isa 53:9 - grave means 6 feet under, even if you accept a tomb - he was by himself in the tomb, not with a rich man & wicked person.  A rich man owning a tomb is far away

@anothertheory - "grave with the wicked" is referring to Jesus' death with two criminals by crucifixion.

@Dottard and the rich man?

@anothertheory - the grave/sepulcher was provided by a wealthy man, namely Joseph of Arimathea as noted above.

@Dottard - you missed an important word 'assigned'  that would imply 'allocated' a grave - not that he died with the wicked.   at best the wicked were allocated the same grave / tomb - regardless if they were placed there or not.  Stretching that to just he was assigned to death with the wicked, would then overlook the word 'grave'

@anothertheory - I will post another question with a corresponding answer to address all your questions.

@Dottard look forward to it please provide the link when you post

@anothertheory - already done as per >>  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/99449/isa-539-grave-of-wicked-or-rich

No. It isn't Jeremiah. It is Jesus Christ, God in the flesh. The unique phrase high and exalted (Ram Venisa [רם ונשא]) is used three times in the Book of Isaiah. In 52:13-15 it describes the Servant. In the other two (6:1, 57:15), God of Israel.

In the year that King Uzziah died, I saw the Lord, high and
exalted, seated on a throne; and the train of his robe filled the
temple. (Isaiah 6:1)
See, my servant will act wisely; he will be raised and lifted up
and highly exalted. Just as there were many who were appalled at him —
his appearance was so disfigured beyond that of any human being and
his form marred beyond human likeness — so he will sprinkle many
nations, and kings will shut their mouths because of him. For what
they were not told, they will see, and what they have not heard, they
will understand. (Isaiah 52:13-15)
For this is what the high and exalted One says— he who lives
forever, whose name is holy: “I live in a high and holy place, but
also with the one who is contrite and lowly in spirit, to revive the
spirit of the lowly and to revive the heart of the contrite. (Isaiah
57:15)

Jeremiah on so many levels was one of the greatest foreshadow of the Messiah. He newer married, prophesied about the destruction of Jerusalem and the temple, foretold the exile, was prosecuted by the religious leaders and the establishment...

ארקדיוס- Your references lack engagement to my question and the Scripture I shared. In Isaiah 52, the primary focus is on the people of Judah, specifically those in exile in Babylon, who are being addressed by the prophet Isaiah with a message of hope and coming deliverance from their captivity, signifying God's promise to restore them to their homeland. Not to be confused with the Messiah. Jesus is Messiah, yes indeed. But my question was to focus on what Jeremiah says, ""But I was like a gentle lamb led to the slaughter. I did not know it was against me they devised schemes, ..."

Down-vote cancelled with an up-vote +1.

An answer deserving of an up-vote.

Answer
Prophet Jeremiah is not the suffering servant portrayed in Isaiah.
Explanation
Jeremiah cannot be the suffering servant of Isaiah for the following reason:

Jeremiah was first “like a gentle lamb” because he “did not know it was against” him“ they devised schemes” (Jer 11:19).

But once he came to know about their schemes, he was no longer that gentle!
He says immediately:

“But, O Jehovah of Hosts who judges with righteousness, who tries the
reins and the heart, let me see Your vengeance on them. For to You
I have laid open my cause” (the very next verse 20).

He says later:

“Yet you, O LORD, know all their plotting to kill me. Forgive not
their iniquity, nor blot out their sin from your sight. Let them be
overthrown before you; deal with them in the time of your anger” (Jer
18:23).

[On the contrary, the Messiah prayed when they were slaughtering Him: “Father, forgive them, for they do not know what they are doing” (Luke 23:34)]

“He was oppressed and afflicted, yet He did not open His mouth……, He did not open His mouth” (OP’s quote).

This cannot be Jeremiah. As a man, he often (more than once) opened his mouth and complained when he was afflicted.
This one is a bit longer:

“Cursed be the day on which I was born! The day when my mother bore
me, let it not be blessed! Cursed be the man who brought the news to
my father, “A son is born to you,” making him very glad. Let that man
be like the cities that the LORD overthrew without pity; let him hear
a cry in the morning and an alarm at noon, because he did not kill me
in the womb; so my mother would have been my grave, and her womb
forever great. Why did I come out from the womb to see toil and
sorrow, and spend my days in shame?” (Jer 20:14-18).


“O LORD, you have deceived me, and I was deceived; you are stronger
than I, and you have prevailed. I have become a laughingstock all the
day; everyone mocks me” (Jer 20:7).

[Hardly a figure to fit the description in Isaiah. But contrast him with the true Messiah how He conducted Himself in the entire Crucifixion!]

“All we like sheep have gone astray, we have turned, each of us, to his own way; and the LORD has laid on him the iniquity of us all” (Isaiah 53:6).

This is impossible to fit the man Jeremiah for the following reasons:
a)  Isaiah emphasizes “all we” to refer to humanity including Jeremiah! So it is pointless to place all the iniquity of the entire humanity which includes Jeremiah’s own iniquity on Jeremiah! God is not that crazy!
b)  If Jeremiah is going to bear the iniquity of ALL on him, then who will bear his own iniquity? For he confesses his sins and iniquity:

“We acknowledge our wickedness, O LORD, and the iniquity of our
fathers, for we have sinned against you” (Jer 14:20).

c)  A sinner cannot bear the sins of other sinners. It requires a sinless One to bear the sins of others. So, by default Jeremiah is a misfit here.
[But the true Messiah fits here perfectly: “For He has made Him who knew no sin, to be sin for us, that we might become the righteousness of God in Him” (2 Cor 5:21)].
Conclusion
In an effort to disprove that Jesus is God, a lot of twisting and misreading of several Scripture verses are attempted unsuccessfully. But the truth shines out like the sun.
Isaiah spoke about Christ who fits the bill perfectly in every way. It is not about Jeremiah.

“He never sinned, and he never told a lie. When he was insulted,
he did not retaliate. When he suffered, he did not threaten. It was
his habit to commit the matter to the one who judges fairly. "He
himself bore our sins" in his body on the tree, so that we might
die to those sins and live righteously. "By his wounds you have been
healed." (1 Pet 2:22-24)


Nephesh Roi- Great explanation without going all over the place!

Thank you, RomanDeLeon. I just limited my answer to the specific area of the question which is just one way of answering.

The suffering servent Isaiah is talking about is the nation of Israel, which was suffering because of the Babylonia Captivity. This is clear because... the text says so quite clearly.

Isaiah 41:8 ‘But you, Israel, my servant,
Jacob, whom I have chosen,
you descendants of Abraham my friend,


Isaiah 44:1 ‘But now listen, Jacob, my servant,
Israel, whom I have chosen.
Isaiah 44:21  ‘Remember these things, Jacob,
for you, Israel, are my servant. I have made you, you are my servant;
Israel, I will not forget you.


Isaiah 49:3 He said to me, ‘You are my servant,
Israel, in whom I will display my splendour.’


welcome to the group F2Andy. Your answer could be improved by responding directly to the OP's question about Jeremiah.

F2Andy- Thank you! I will accept your answer as being correct!

If you are looking only at the word “servant”, then it could be Isaiah himself (“My servant Isaiah” – Is 20:3), or Eliakim (“My servant Eliakim” – Is 22:20) or even King David (“My servant David” – Is 37:35).

Are you referring to the suffering servant in Isaiah 53 in your answer?

The servant in Isaiah 53 bears the sins of Israel, and so can’t be Israel.

The OP's question needs some more clarity. But, if we're all correct as to the focal point of scripture wherein someone is called a suffering servant, the first verse to come to my mind is in Isaiah 53. Once the OP's question is better understood scripturally, maybe the clarity about Jeremiah's place or lack of it in Isaiah will be better understood. According to history, if it matters in this case of this question, Jeremiah and Isaiah were not alive during the same time.

As Dottard's answer shows, the New Testament repeatedly identifies the servant in Isaiah 53 with Jesus. So it is not surprising Jewish commentators, who reject the belief Jesus is the Christ, would attempt to find an alternative explanation for Isaiah 53.
However, it should be obvious from the Hebrew text the passage in Isaiah cannot be applied to Jeremiah.

7 He was oppressed, and he was afflicted,
yet he opened not his mouth;
like a lamb, כּשּׂה that is led to the slaughter,
and like a sheep וּכרחל that before its shearers is silent,
so he opened not his mouth. 8 By oppression and judgment he was taken away; and as for his generation, who considered
that he was cut off נגזר out of the land of the living,
stricken for the transgression of my people?
(Isaiah 53 ESV)


But I was like a gentle lamb כּכבשׂ
led to the slaughter.
I did not know it was against me
they devised schemes, saying,
“Let us destroy the tree with its fruit,
let us cut him off ונכרתנּוּ from the land of the living,
that his name be remembered no more.”
(Jeremiah 11:19)

The lamb in Isaiah is שֶׂה; in Jeremiah it is כֶּבֶשׂ.
Cut off in Isaiah is גָּזַר; in Jeremiah it is כָּרַת
          Isaiah     Jeremiah
Lamb      śê         keḇeś    
Cut off   gāzar      kāraṯ

Isaiah describes the servant using a different animal and a different type of being cut off. This is especially so in the case of being cut off. The term in Jeremiah, kāraṯ describes being cut off of the covenant. It is used extensively in the Mosaic Law. gāzar is not used in the Mosaic Law and is used to describe being divided, cut down, or destroyed.

One of the most notable proof that the "servant" is not a single individual is Isaiah 43:10 where the "servant" (singular) is identified as God's "witnesses" (plural).
The righteous remnant of Israel is imparted in Psalm 44:22 and Zechariah 11 4-7. There is no unequivocal reference in these verses of the Messiah being called a lamb. The condition of the Jewish people in these verses matches Isaiah 53.
Notice the use of the Hebrew pronoun (lamo) in Isaiah 53:8. Isaiah did not intend to speak of a single individual in the plural. This shows that the "servant" of Isaiah 53 is not a single individual. Thus, the mistranslation of "them" to "him" in Isaiah 53:8 by some bibles is inconsistent as a comparison of their correct translation of the same word show in Genesis 9:26, Deuteronomy 32:2, Job 6:19, Psalms 2:4, Isaiah 23:1, Isaiah 16:4 to cite a few.
In addition,the mistranslation of (b'motov) in Isaiah 53:8, his "deaths" (plural) to his "death" (singular)  misleads the reader of the identity of the servant, which is the Jewish people and not a single individual.
The chapters before Isaiah 53, Isaiah 41:8-9 and Isaiah 44:1-2, clearly identifies the nation of Israel as the servant. Isaiah 44:21, Isaiah 45:4, Isaiah 48:20, Isaiah 49:3, Psalm 126:22, Jeremiah 30:10, Jeremiah 46:27-28 further confirm the identity of the servant as the nation of Israel.
Reading history backwards to study objectively tends to overlook factors that are apparent.

I will share an answer for the lack of time, not to proof I am right. To begin with, Isaiah in Chapter 53 is not the Isaiah after whom the book is
named. He is not the Isaiah of Chapters 1 through 39, who talks about world
peace at the end of days, or tells us that the young woman [traditionally translated in Christian Bibles as the "virgin"] is with child. Jewish interpretations of the Book of Isaiah have struggled for the past 2,000 years with the question of the identity of the author or authors of the second half of the book, that begins with Chapter 40. For one thing, it is quite clear that the second half refers to events around the time of the return from the Babylonian Exile, more than two centuries after the time of Isaiah. An early example (around the second century C.E.) of the awareness of an author different from the original one is found in the Talmud in a discussion of the order and authorship of the books of the Bible, in which Isaiah is placed after Jeremiah and Ezekiel (Bava Batra 14b). The sages, however, are not comfortable with this arrangement and engage in a discussion trying to solve this discrepancy.
The question comes into sharper focus in the work of medieval Jewish
commentators. A century ago, Thomas Kelly Cheyne wrote: "Two eminent
Jewish rabbis, Abraham Ibn Ezra and Isaac Abravanel, were the first who
showed a tendency to disintegrate the Book of Isaiah, but their subtle suggestion had no consequences." Actually, they were preceded by Ibn Gikatilla, who is mentioned by Ibn Ezra in his commentary on Isaiah 40:1. In this context the two clearly point to two Isaiahs. Further allusions to the issue appear in the work of Rambam, who, at the end of his discussion of the yearly cycle of prayers, refers to the "prayers of consolation of Isaiah" as though it were a later unit of the book, and also in Ramban.
The ambiguity of this issue does not end even in modern times. In his introduction to his commentary on Isaiah, Israel Slotki asserts the existence of three Isaiahs. To this day, opinions differ on the issue of the authorship of the second half of the book. There is now, however, a general consensus.
It appears that the Second Isaiah knew the answer, but as with his own
identity, it was kept a secret. It also appears that someone else at a later date knew the Servant's identity. To find the answer, we need to turn to the Book of Jeremiah. A better understanding of Jeremiah is essential to understanding the Second Isaiah and his mysterious Servant, and the method available to us is a textual and linguistic analysis of the words of those two prophets. That Jeremiah has a great deal to do with the Suffering Servant is something that was observed at least as early as the tenth century by Saadia Gaon, the great philosopher and exegete. According to Ibn Ezra, in his commentary on Isaiah 52:13, Saadia identified the Servant with Jeremiah, an interprertation that Ibn Ezra (12th century) concurred with: "The Gaon, Rav Saadia, his memory be blessed, interpreted the whole chapter as referring to Jeremiah, and well he interpreted." But Saadia's view was rejected in his own lifetime, particularly by his Karaite adversaries, who contended that he had lost his senses. (The Karaites, a Jewish sect that still exists today, were strict literalists when it came to biblical interpretation, rejecting rabbinical interpretations and innovations.) Sheldon Blank, a 20th-century Jewish biblical scholar who
has written books about both Jeremiah and Isaiah, rejects the view that the
Servant is Jeremiah. Blank writes: The bitter experience of Israel, whom the Second Isaiah here personified as servant-prophet, led him necessarily to Jeremiah for the features of his personification – to that prophet within his tradition who, more than any other, had, like Israel, endured reproach and suffering. Inevitably, Jeremiah must sit as model for his portrait of
God's servant-prophet. This is not to say that the servant and Jeremiah are to be identified.
R.E.O. White, a Christian contemporary of Blank who also wrote a book
about Jeremiah, has this to say about the identity of the Servant:
So Isaiah sketches his portrait of the coming Servant of the Lord
who should save Israel, and in that portrait Jesus himself saw his
own lineaments and destiny prefigured. But of whom was Isaiah thinking of when he asked his questions? With Jeremiah's story in
mind, we may reverently wonder if the words do not describe his
experience with astonishing accuracy. And reverent surmise becomes moral certainty when we hear Isaiah at once quote Jeremiah's
words about himself:
"But I was like a gentle lamb led to the
slaughter. I did not know it was against me they devised schemes,
saying, . . .'Let us cut him off from the land of the living'" (Jer.
11:19; cf. Isa. 53:7-8).
What makes these two quotes from two contemporary biblical scholars so
telling is that even though they both sense the strong presence of Jeremiah in Isaiah 53, they are wedded to their traditional views of the Servant being the Jewish people (for Blank), and Jesus (for White). Neither one of them goes far enough in analyzing these difficult verses in which the Mystery Prophet embedded a unique message, left for future generations to be deciphered.
This message amounts to a capsule biography of Jeremiah, who is indeed the Servant in these verses:
Who can believe what we have heard? And on whom was Adonai's power revealed?(Isa. 53:1).
The story of Jeremiah is absolutely amazing. Jeremiah lived during the last
years of the Judean monarchy. He foresaw the coming destruction of Jerusalem, and spent his years as a solitary voice calling his people to turn back from their evil ways. He was scorned and ridiculed, and on several occasions he came within a hair's-breadth of losing his life. It was only after the fall of Judah that the exiles in Babylon began to realize that his was the voice of God. For a while his story was unknown in Babylon, but when the Second Isaiah first heard it he was amazed to learn what Jeremiah had gone through, and how God chose such an afflicted person as his messenger. Indeed, Jeremiah should be credited for saving Judaism. He did much more than prophesy doom. With the help of the scribe Baruch ben-Neriah, he began the process of preserving the Law and transitioning Judaism from a religion centered around Temple sacrifices to a faith based on Torah, prayer and ethical behavior.
In this respect, Jeremiah may be considered the first Jew, while Abraham is the first Hebrew.
In comparing the language of Isaiah 53 to Jeremiah's, it is clear that this Mystery Prophet was a disciple of Jeremiah, in whom he saw the savior of Judaism. Jeremiah to him becomes the prophet par excellence, the true servant of God. As the pivotal prophet in the Bible, Jeremiah comes to embody for the Second Isaiah the entire Jewish people, and so the Servant becomes interchangeably Jeremiah and the Jewish people. Why Second Isaiah does not come out and identify Jeremiah by name will be discussed later on.
He rose like a newborn baby before Him, And like a tree
trunk in an arid land (53:2). This is a direct biographical reference to Jeremiah. We are told in Jeremiah 1 that God chose Jeremiah at his birth. We are further told that when God first appears to Jeremiah, the young boy is looking at a blossoming almond tree. The boy is overwhelmed by his first contact with the Divine, and when he rises and watches the tree in full blossom, the voice of God becomes his. He is told not to fear, for he will be made strong against his adversaries. The two words "arid land" are borrowed from the next episode in the Book of Jeremiah (2:6), where the prophet reminds his people of the wandering through the desert: Who leads us . . . through arid land. He had no rank and was given no respect, We did not find anything attractive about him (53:2).
Jeremiah was born a priest but gave up his priestly rank. He was not an
official prophet of the court until the very end, when a desperate King Zedekiah began to consult him without actually engaging him as a court priest. Jeremiah's contemporaries showed him no respect. At best, he was tolerated.
A man of constant sorrow, he made few friends and had little influence over
his contemporaries, who were too far gone in their idolatry and immorality to understand his message.
He was despised, shunned by all, A great sufferer, greatly afflicted (53:3).
Jeremiah was the most afflicted prophet in the Hebrew Bible. He foresaw
the destruction of Jerusalem years before it happened, and mourned it for
many years.
The Judeans, particularly in Jerusalem, despised him, for he disturbed their complacency and smugness. (God was on their side, they argued,
and no harm would come to them.)
He seemed to hide from us, Despised, we took no account of him (53:3).
Hiding is a running theme in Jeremiah's life. After he prophesies at the
Temple, the priests try to put him to death. He is banned from the public and goes into hiding. Later, after King Jehoiakim throws Jeremiah's scroll of prophecies into the fire, he has to go into hiding again to save his life.
Indeed, he carried our affliction, And he suffered our pain (53:4).
No other prophet in the Bible suffers the pain of his people more vividly
than does Jeremiah. When the Temple is destroyed and the people are exiled,
Jeremiah takes on the suffering of his people and, according to rabbinic tradition, authors the Book of Lamentations, Judaism's official lament for the destruction of the Temple. And we thought him diseased, God stricken, tortured (53:4).
When Jeremiah parades in the streets of Jerusalem in a soiled and soggy
loincloth, or with iron bars around his neck, he certainly does not convey the image of a happy and level-headed person. He is repeatedly scorned by his listeners, and rather than see him as God's messenger, they regard him as a misguided and tortured soul.
But he was stricken because of our sins (53:5). God indeed makes Jeremiah carry the burden of the sins of his generation.
Oppressed because of our iniquities,
The lesson of our welfare is upon him (53:5).
The life of Jeremiah and his teaching were an object lesson for his generation. That they recovered their national welfare was because of him and the legacy he bequeathed them, namely, the Torah and prophetic teachings he helped preserve for them with the help of his scribe, Baruch ben-Neriah.
And in his bruises we were healed. We all went astray like sheep (53:5-6).
When Jeremiah is flogged, or when he is lowered into the mud pit, he
emerges full of bruises. But he is doing it for the sake of his people, who
went astray and did not see the impending doom. Each going our own way, And God visited upon him the guilt of us all (53:6).
The people were divided during the time of the siege of Jerusalem, and
Jeremiah had to live through that time of national divisiveness and bear its
consequences. This continued during the fall of Jerusalem to the Babylonians, and after the assassination of Gedaliah, whom they had appointed governor.
He was attacked, yet he remained submissive, He did not open his mouth
(53:7) When the priests in the Holy Temple try to pass a death sentence on Jeremiah, he humbly accepts his fate, and is only saved by the last-minute intercession of a highly-placed friend.
He was led like a sheep to the slaughter,
Silent like a ewe about to be sheared (53:7).
Here we have Jeremiah's own words being quoted: But I was like a gentle
sheep led to the slaughter (Jer. 11:19).
To the Second Isaiah, Jeremiah came to symbolize the Suffering Servant,
whom God chose to help save His covenanted people. In a broader sense, the
Servant is the Jewish people as a whole. Why, then, does the author fail to
identify Jeremiah by name?
To begin with, the Second Isaiah does not identify anyone by name, not
even himself. He remains the Mystery Prophet throughout. But it should be
clear by now that he knew Jeremiah quite well, and was greatly influenced by
him. Furthermore, since his prophecies were inserted into an already-existing book, namely, the Book of Isaiah, it is clear that other hands were involved in the compilation of the book as we know it. (It is a rather ancient compilation, dating back before the Common Era, as evidenced by the Isaiah scroll found among the Dead Sea Scrolls.)

Are you suggesting that Isa 40-66 is a forgery?  Presumably written by someone else than it claims to be?  If so, it is unworthy of any attention whatsoever!  The NT writers were also mistaken in their (inspired) belief that the second half of Isaiah was written by Isaiah as well.

This is opinion based and not an aademic study.

The inspired words of Jeremiah 8:8 “How can you say, ‘We are wise, And the law of the LORD is with us’? Look, the false pen of the scribe certainly works falsehood. NT 'inspired' we don’t even know who wrote the gospels, the originals were lost long before, hence so many issues

Although I do not agree with the proposition, I upvoted this answer as "useful" for understanding the various interpretations of Is. 53. I especially appreciate the research that went into this answer . BTW, In addition to the usual Jewish answer that the Servant is Israel, two other candidates should be mentioned: Hezekiah and Zedekiah.
