Isa 53:9 - Grave of wicked or rich?
As commonly Translated, Isa 53:9 begins with (my literal translation):

His grave was assigned with the wicked, and with the rich in his
death, ...

This is widely (but not universally) understood to be a Messianic prophecy about Jesus Christ.  Assuming that to be correct for the sake of this question, how can the above apparent contradiction be resolved?
[Note: This question and answer is intended to address numerous questions posed in the comments of  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/99405/is-isaiahs-suffering-servant-the-prophet-jeremiah/99414?noredirect=1#comment204093_99414  ]

Can you support the concept 'a rich man' (Hebrew has no so-called 'indefinite' article) as the tranlsations I have looked at express 'rich' as a concept - 'the rich' - rather than identify a single individual. Thus, being in the sepulchre of 'the rich' is envisaged rather than lying in a sepulchre 'with a rich man'.

@NigelJ - OK, I will update the wording

This is a well-known question for which the simplest solution is provided by a nuanced translation of the initial verb of Isa 53:9, namely: נָתַן (nathan) = "to give, put or set" (Strong's).  It occurs over 2000 times in the OT and obviously includes a range of meaning, eg, BDB includes this meaning: "to grant" or "bestow' or "allocate", etc.
Thus, it is possible to translate the verse as:

He was allocated a grave with the wicked but with the rich in death
...

Indeed, Benson suggests this:

... the words may be rendered, "A grave was appointed for him with
the wicked; but he was with the rich at his death". Or, as Bishop
Lowth reads it, "His grave was appointed with the wicked; but with
the rich man was his tomb". See his notes. “As our Lord was crucified
between two thieves, it was doubtless intended he should be buried
with them. ‘Thus his grave was appointed with the wicked;’ but Joseph
of Arimathea came and asked for his body, and Pilate, convinced that
he had committed no crime, readily granted Joseph’s request. Thus ‘he
was with the rich at his death,’ that is, till his resurrection: and
this took place contrary to the intention of his enemies, because he
had done no violence, &c., for otherwise Joseph would scarcely have
requested Pilate, and probably Pilate would not have consented, to
deliver up the body of a crucified malefactor.” — Scott.

The Cambridge commentary and Matthew Poole offer similar comments.
This was definitely fulfilled by Jesus because:

Jesus was crucified with criminals - a most ignominious death, most of whom were never buried but either burned or simply thrown into the valley of Hinnom, Matt 27:38, Luke 22:37.
Despite the above, Jesus was given the equivalent of a wealthy man's burial by being laid in the new tomb of Joseph of Arimathea, Matt 27:57-60.


+1 This is the best way to reconcile the verses assuming they were meant to apply to Jesus.  I'll provide an alternative answer, based on the idea that "the rich" may be synonymous with "the wicked."

I agree with @Dottard's answer, but here is an alternative way to reconcile the verse:
In Hebrew poetry, a second verse often reiterates the first. Examples include:

The cords of death entangled me; the torrents of destruction overwhelmed me. The cords of the grave coiled around me; the snares of death confronted me.” -Psalm 18:4-5

He was pierced for our transgressions, he was crushed for our iniquities. 53:5a


Isaiah 53:9 may also be read this way. In other words: His grave was 'assigned with the wicked' means basically the same thing as 'with the rich in his death.' Supporting this idea is the fact that Jesus often spoke against the rich. The story of the Rich Man and Lazarus (Luke 16) is but one example. All three synoptic gospels say that it is practically impossible for a rich man to enter heaven. (Mark 10:25 etc.) In addition Luke 6:20 tells us that the kingdom of heaven belongs to the poor.
These things considered, it may be that we do not need to reconcile the idea of Jesus being assigned a grave with the wicked and the idea that he was given grave with the rich. In Jesus' preaching - it may be argued - no rich man is righteous, and being rich is actually an obstacle to salvation.
The main objection to this hypothesis is the fact that Jesus' tomb belonged to a wealthy man who seems to have been an exception to this rule. However, some Christians (especially liberation theologians and others who affirm a biblical preference for the poor) may indeed see "the wicked" and "the rich" as similar categories.

Many thanks for these very helpful remarks. +1.
