Why is the servant in Isaiah 43:10 identified as"witnesses" instead of "witness"? Is the servant a singular individual?
Isaiah 43:10 ASV
Ye are my witnesses, saith Jehovah, and my servant whom I have chosen; that ye may know and believe me, and understand that I am he: before me there was no God formed, neither shall there be after me.


10 You are my witnesses—oracle of the Lord—
my servant whom I have chosen
To know and believe in me
and understand that I am he.
Before me no god was formed,
and after me there shall be none.
11 I, I am the Lord;
there is no savior but me.
12 It is I who declared, who saved,
who announced, not some strange god among you;
You are my witnesses—oracle of the Lord.
I am God,
13     yes, from eternity I am he;

The simplest answer here is that the servant refers to the collective nation of Israel. God addresses his people as "my servant" and calls them to witness, for they have not lived up to their covenant. The nation is one 'servant' but those called from it to be witnesses are many.
For Christians, this need not contradict the idea that Jesus is the suffering servant of Isaiah 53. Here, however it seems clear that the servant is a collective noun standing for Israel, for later in the same chapter we read:

I put water in the wilderness
and rivers in the wasteland
for my chosen people to drink, 21 The people whom I formed for myself,
that they might recount my praise.
22 Yet you did not call upon me, Jacob,
for you grew weary of me, Israel.


@DanFefferman.Is the servant in Isaia 43:10 different from the servant in Isaiah 53?

@AlexBalilo -  There are only four servant songs referring to Jesus in Isaiah: 1 - Isaiah 42:1–4; 2 - Isaiah 49:1–6; 3 - Isaiah 50:4–11; 4 - Isaiah 52:13–53:12.  Isa 43 is NOT about the suffering servant.  It is God speaking to Israel.

+1. Good answer.

@DanFefferman. Like you said "for Christians" Is the Christians' view of the Hebrew scripture the correct interpretation?

@AlexBalilo.... That is a matter of theological opinion. However I think Christians can admit that the earlier Servant Songs are about Israel... see Dottard's comment.

@DanFefferman. Since you can't definitely prove that the Christians' view of the Hebrew scriptures is the correct interpretation,  some of your answer then is based on opinion.

Taking this from the simplest angle, we can see from Isaiah 42-44 that this relates to the Israelites.
Isaiah 42:

6 "I, the LORD , have called you in righteousness; I will take hold of your hand. I will keep you and will make you to be a covenant for the people and a light for the Gentiles,
13 The LORD will march out like a mighty man, like a warrior he will stir up his zeal; with a shout he will raise the battle cry and will triumph over his enemies.
18 "Hear, you deaf; look, you blind, and see!
24 Who handed Jacob over to become loot, and Israel to the plunderers? Was it not the LORD ,

Isaiah 43:

1 But now, this is what the LORD says- he who created you, O Jacob, he who formed you, O Israel: "Fear not, for I have redeemed you; I have summoned you by name; you are mine.
5 Do not be afraid, for I am with you; I will bring your children from the east and gather you from the west.
6 I will say to the north, 'Give them up!' and to the south, 'Do not hold them back.' Bring my sons from afar and my daughters from the ends of the earth-
22 "Yet you have not called upon me, O Jacob, you have not wearied yourselves for me, O Israel.
25 "I, even I, am he who blots out your transgressions, for my own sake, and remembers your sins no more.
28 So I will disgrace the dignitaries of your temple, and I will consign Jacob to destruction and Israel to scorn.

Isaiah 44:

1 "But now listen, O Jacob, my servant, Israel, whom I have chosen.
6 "This is what the LORD says- Israel's King and Redeemer, the LORD Almighty: I am the first and I am the last; apart from me there is no God
21 "Remember these things, O Jacob, for you are my servant, O Israel. I have made you, you are my servant; O Israel, I will not forget you.
22 I have swept away your offenses like a cloud, your sins like the morning mist. Return to me, for I have redeemed you."

Conclusion
I’ve only taken a few passages; however, it is clear that 42-44 is talking collectively about Israel and not about one individual.  There are numerous passages, within the chapters that clearly do not relate to Jesus and relates to a nation not an individual.
Jesus was not sent to the Gentiles, never participated in war, never needed to be redeemed etc…
This and a number of other Isaiah chapters talk about God cursing, forgiving, redeeming the Israelites.
So, no Isaiah 43 does not relate to Jesus and neither does Isaiah 53 (see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/82915/33268) that many like to link this to, or indeed Isaiah 42.

I am not ever tired to repeat a couple of pivotal points that we have to consider when we are approaching to understand a Bible passage:
One
There is a huge difference between who try to understand a Bible passage having a ‘lay’ (‘laic’) viewpoint, respect to who have a ‘believer’ viewpoint.
The first guy, indeed, is interested to all aspects of the word construction of the text (grammar, syntax, idiom, et caetera) but will discard the aspects related to the grasping of God’s qualities, that often are behind a given Bible text.
The latter guy, instead, above to consider the same aspects of the first one, ask to himself, too: ‘Is this explanation consistent with the divine qualities I’ve drawn from the rest of Bible message, or, also, from the universal phenomena (Rom 1:20)?’ In other words, a believer have to ascertain also that a given explanation of a Bible passage is consistent with the context (micro- and macro-) of the Scripture itself.
Two
In the same manner, a believer researcher have to understand that ‘Bible’ is not, necessarily, the book (or, books, if we have many translations of it) we have in our shelf, but the text that we can reconstruct, derived from a collation from all the available text that contain God’s message to humankind.
Granted, to reach this aim we have to utilize all the instruments that are necessary to accomplish this goal, for example, an expertise of the texts’ original languages, the textual criticism principles, the use of logic (Rom 12:1), the comparison of a given explanation with the God’s qualities, and the context (as I’ve explained, in a very synthetical way in the previous paragraph).
Said this, let’s start.
Grammar
As regards MT (Masoretic Texts), the Hebrew expression עבדי (often translated ‘my servant’ [י + עבד]) may be used (like a lot of other espressions, or nouns, anyway) in either sense, individual, or collective.
Using the individual sense of the noun we may conclude that עבדי there refers to a single people. In this instance, the higher probability stands for the Messiah as the עבדי identity.
Whereas, using the collective sense of the noun we may conclude that the עבדי there refers to a group of people (bounded by a common goal). In this instance, the higher probability stands for the people of Israel as the עבדי identity.
So, from this grammar sole point of view we have to remain in a stalemate position, about the identity of that עבדי.
But, as you surely guess, there are other aspects to consider.

Other Texts
What about another text, namely, the Septuagint?
A comparison between the MT text and the Septuagint text will show a different phraseology.
The LXX says (according the NETS translation):
“Be my witnesses; I too am a witness, says the Lord God, and the servant [παῖς (pais)] whom I have chosen so that you may know and believe and understand that I am.”
In this text, after having invited the Israelites to be witnesses of the great work of Him, the Lord God - in His turn - presented himself as a witness for the sake of His people, giving witness that the Israelites “may know and believe and understand that I am”.

Logic
Note how the ‘servant’ [παῖς (pais)] of God here, too, acts ad a witness for Israel’s sake. This specific phraseology makes difficult to apply here the title ‘servant’ [παῖς (pais)] to the people of Israel. In fact, if the ‘servant’ [παῖς (pais)] of God here were the Israelites, were they able to give witness to ourselves? In higher probability, in this Isaiah text is presented the idea of some individual that act as witnesses reciprocally, namely, the Israelites as witnesses to confirm the marvellous acts of Jehovah for their salvation, and God Himself, along with his ‘servant’ [παῖς (pais)] as witnesses that the Israelites “may know and believe and understand that [God is]”.

Context (micro- and macro-)
The Hebrew expression utilized by Isaiah, עבדי, “my servant”, is utilized again by the prophet in other points of his writing, points that are clearly linked to the Messiah:
Isa 42:1 “Behold my servant [עבדי], whom I uphold, my chosen, in whom my soul delights; I have put my Spirit upon him; he will bring forth justice to the nations.”, ESV.
Isa 52:13: “Behold, my servant [עבדי] shall act wisely, he shall be high and lifted up, and shall be exalted.”, ESV.
Isa 53:11: “…out of the anguish of his soul he shall see and be satisfied, by his knowledge shall the righteous one, my servant [עבדי] make many to be accounted righteous, and he shall bear their iniquities.”, ESV.
So, can we safely exclude that also in Isa 43:10 that expression were linked to the Messiah?
Moreover, also the analogous LXX’s Greek term [παῖς (pais), from this term is derived the English term ‘pedagogy’] enlightes us.
At least 4 times the NT apply this special title to the Messiah Jesus:
Acts 3:13 - “The God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, the God of our fathers, glorified his servant [παῖς (pais)] Jesus, whom you delivered over and denied in the presence of Pilate, when he had decided to release him.”, ESV.
Acts 3:26 - “The God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, the God of our fathers, glorified his servant [παῖς (pais)] Jesus, whom you delivered over and denied in the presence of Pilate, when he had decided to release him.”, ESV.
Acts 4:27 - “for truly in this city there were gathered together against your holy servant [παῖς (pais)] Jesus, whom you anointed, both Herod and Pontius Pilate, along with the Gentiles and the peoples of Israel.”, ESV.
Acts 4:30 – “while you stretch out your hand to heal, and signs and wonders are performed through the name of your holy servant [παῖς (pais)] Jesus.”, ESV.
In a commentary to the book of the prophet Isaiah (Il Libro di Isaia, p. 447), Marco Sales and Giuseppe Girotti wrote (mine translation): “In his talk to the people, S. Peter (Acts 3, 13, 26) calls Jesus ‘Servant [παῖς (pais)] of God’. [He gave to Jesus] the messianic title utilized by the prophet [Isaiah]: ‘Ebed’; Isaiah 42, 1; 52, 13, [term that] the LXX translated as παῖς. It is passed in the early Christian literature: Clemens (1 to Corinthians 59, 2), Didaché (9, 2; 10, 3), Barnabas (Epistle 6, 1).”
With regard to this, another clue is presented by John Gill (Exposition), quoting what the Targum said: “[…] the Targum, ‘and my servant the Messiah, in whom I am well pleased’; and who is called the faithful witness, Rev 1:5, and to whom the characters of a servant, and the Lord’s chosen, well agree, Isa 42:1.” (this reading of the Targum is confirmed also by James Blenkisopp, in The Anchor Bible – vol. 19°, Isaiah 40-55 p. 224)
What about the ancient commentators?
All the following guys, namely, Iraeneus of Lyon (Adv. Haer, 3.6.2), Origen of Alexandria (Commentary on John 2.209, Exhortation to Martirdom, 34), as well as Eusebius of Caesarea (Eclogae Propheticae 4.2.1, Commentary on Isaiah, 278-279) agreed that the expression ‘my servant’, on Isa 43:10, referred to the Messiah Jesus.

So, if we sum up this evidence showed above, the more probable conclusion is that, in the specific case of Isaiah 43:10, the ‘servant’ outlined there was the Messiah, not the people of Israel. As God invited the Israelites to become witnesses of His glory, God himself, along with his ‘servant’ – the Messiah – at Israel’s disposal, to witness that they “may know and believe and understand that [God is].”
Last thought (only for committed Christians): Are we acting as witnesses to God’s glory, with all our conduct, so that God and the Messiah, as their part, witness at our sake, for our salvation?
